# Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How Can I query an RDD with complex types such as maps/arrays?
for example, when I was writing this test code:

```
case class Test(name: String, map: Map[String, String])
val map = Map("hello" -> "world", "hey" -> "there")
val map2 = Map("hello" -> "people", "hey" -> "you")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(Test("first", map), Test("second", map2)))
```

I thought the syntax would be something like:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM rdd WHERE map.hello = world")
```

or

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM rdd WHERE map[hello] = world")
```

but I get

> Can't access nested field in type MapType(StringType,StringType,true)

and

> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Unresolved attributes

respectively.

Comment: I upvoted the accepted answer, it is an excellent source for all the ways to query complex fields.  As a quick reference for those doing this:  the reason `map[hello]` doesn't work is that the key is a string field, so you must quote it:  `map['hello']`.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

It depends on a type of the column. Lets start with some dummy data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, lit}
import scala.util.Try

case class SubRecord(x: Int)
case class ArrayElement(foo: String, bar: Int, vals: Array[Double])
case class Record(
  an_array: Array[Int], a_map: Map[String, String], 
  a_struct: SubRecord, an_array_of_structs: Array[ArrayElement])


val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Record(Array(1, 2, 3), Map("foo" -> "bar"), SubRecord(1),
         Array(
           ArrayElement("foo", 1, Array(1.0, 2.0, 2.0)),
           ArrayElement("bar", 2, Array(3.0, 4.0, 5.0)))),
  Record(Array(4, 5, 6), Map("foz" -> "baz"), SubRecord(2),
         Array(ArrayElement("foz", 3, Array(5.0, 6.0)), 
               ArrayElement("baz", 4, Array(7.0, 8.0))))
)).toDF
```

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
df.printSchema

// root
// |-- an_array: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
// |-- a_map: map (nullable = true)
// |    |-- key: string
// |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
// |-- a_struct: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- x: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- an_array_of_structs: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- bar: integer (nullable = false)
// |    |    |-- vals: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

- array (`ArrayType`) columns:

  - `Column.getItem` method

    ```
    df.select($"an_array".getItem(1)).show

    // +-----------+
    // |an_array[1]|
    // +-----------+
    // |          2|
    // |          5|
    // +-----------+
    ```
  - Hive brackets syntax:

    ```
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT an_array[1] FROM df").show

    // +---+
    // |_c0|
    // +---+
    // |  2|
    // |  5|
    // +---+
    ```
  - an UDF

    ```
    val get_ith = udf((xs: Seq[Int], i: Int) => Try(xs(i)).toOption)

    df.select(get_ith($"an_array", lit(1))).show

    // +---------------+
    // |UDF(an_array,1)|
    // +---------------+
    // |              2|
    // |              5|
    // +---------------+
    ```
  - Additionally to the methods listed above Spark supports a growing list of built-in functions operating on complex types. Notable examples include higher order functions like `transform` (SQL 2.4+, Scala 3.0+, PySpark / SparkR 3.1+):

    ```
    df.selectExpr("transform(an_array, x -> x + 1) an_array_inc").show
    // +------------+
    // |an_array_inc|
    // +------------+
    // |   [2, 3, 4]|
    // |   [5, 6, 7]|
    // +------------+

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.transform

    df.select(transform($"an_array", x => x + 1) as "an_array_inc").show
    // +------------+
    // |an_array_inc|
    // +------------+
    // |   [2, 3, 4]|
    // |   [5, 6, 7]|
    // +------------+
    ```
  - `filter` (SQL 2.4+, Scala 3.0+, Python / SparkR 3.1+)

    ```
    df.selectExpr("filter(an_array, x -> x % 2 == 0) an_array_even").show
    // +-------------+
    // |an_array_even|
    // +-------------+
    // |          [2]|
    // |       [4, 6]|
    // +-------------+

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.filter

    df.select(filter($"an_array", x => x % 2 === 0) as "an_array_even").show
    // +-------------+
    // |an_array_even|
    // +-------------+
    // |          [2]|
    // |       [4, 6]|
    // +-------------+
    ```
  - `aggregate` (SQL 2.4+, Scala 3.0+, PySpark / SparkR 3.1+):

    ```
    df.selectExpr("aggregate(an_array, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc) an_array_sum").show
    // +------------+
    // |an_array_sum|
    // +------------+
    // |           6|
    // |          15|
    // +------------+

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.aggregate

    df.select(aggregate($"an_array", lit(0), (x, y) => x + y) as "an_array_sum").show
    // +------------+                                                                  
    // |an_array_sum|
    // +------------+
    // |           6|
    // |          15|
    // +------------+
    ```
  - array processing functions (`array_*`) like `array_distinct` (2.4+):

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_distinct

    df.select(array_distinct($"an_array_of_structs.vals"(0))).show
    // +-------------------------------------------+
    // |array_distinct(an_array_of_structs.vals[0])|
    // +-------------------------------------------+
    // |                                 [1.0, 2.0]|
    // |                                 [5.0, 6.0]|
    // +-------------------------------------------+
    ```
  - `array_max` (`array_min`, 2.4+):

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_max

    df.select(array_max($"an_array")).show
    // +-------------------+
    // |array_max(an_array)|
    // +-------------------+
    // |                  3|
    // |                  6|
    // +-------------------+
    ```
  - `flatten` (2.4+)

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.flatten

    df.select(flatten($"an_array_of_structs.vals")).show
    // +---------------------------------+
    // |flatten(an_array_of_structs.vals)|
    // +---------------------------------+
    // |             [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3...|
    // |             [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]|
    // +---------------------------------+
    ```
  - `arrays_zip` (2.4+):

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.arrays_zip

    df.select(arrays_zip($"an_array_of_structs.vals"(0), $"an_array_of_structs.vals"(1))).show(false)
    // +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    // |arrays_zip(an_array_of_structs.vals[0], an_array_of_structs.vals[1])|
    // +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    // |[[1.0, 3.0], [2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 5.0]]                                |
    // |[[5.0, 7.0], [6.0, 8.0]]                                            |
    // +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    ```
  - `array_union` (2.4+):

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_union

    df.select(array_union($"an_array_of_structs.vals"(0), $"an_array_of_structs.vals"(1))).show
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
    // |array_union(an_array_of_structs.vals[0], an_array_of_structs.vals[1])|
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
    // |                                                 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4...|
    // |                                                 [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]|
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
    ```
  - `slice` (2.4+):

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.slice

    df.select(slice($"an_array", 2, 2)).show
    // +---------------------+
    // |slice(an_array, 2, 2)|
    // +---------------------+
    // |               [2, 3]|
    // |               [5, 6]|
    // +---------------------+
    ```
- map (`MapType`) columns

  - using `Column.getField` method:

    ```
    df.select($"a_map".getField("foo")).show

    // +----------+
    // |a_map[foo]|
    // +----------+
    // |       bar|
    // |      null|
    // +----------+
    ```
  - using Hive brackets syntax:

    ```
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT a_map['foz'] FROM df").show

    // +----+
    // | _c0|
    // +----+
    // |null|
    // | baz|
    // +----+
    ```
  - using a full path with dot syntax:

    ```
    df.select($"a_map.foo").show

    // +----+
    // | foo|
    // +----+
    // | bar|
    // |null|
    // +----+
    ```
  - using an UDF

    ```
    val get_field = udf((kvs: Map[String, String], k: String) => kvs.get(k))

    df.select(get_field($"a_map", lit("foo"))).show

    // +--------------+
    // |UDF(a_map,foo)|
    // +--------------+
    // |           bar|
    // |          null|
    // +--------------+
    ```
  - Growing number of `map_*` functions like `map_keys` (2.3+)

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map_keys

    df.select(map_keys($"a_map")).show
    // +---------------+
    // |map_keys(a_map)|
    // +---------------+
    // |          [foo]|
    // |          [foz]|
    // +---------------+
    ```
  - or `map_values` (2.3+)

    ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map_values

    df.select(map_values($"a_map")).show
    // +-----------------+
    // |map_values(a_map)|
    // +-----------------+
    // |            [bar]|
    // |            [baz]|
    // +-----------------+
    ```

  Please check [SPARK-23899](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23899) for a detailed list.
- struct (`StructType`) columns using full path with dot syntax:

  - with DataFrame API

    ```
    df.select($"a_struct.x").show

    // +---+
    // |  x|
    // +---+
    // |  1|
    // |  2|
    // +---+
    ```
  - with raw SQL

    ```
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT a_struct.x FROM df").show

    // +---+
    // |  x|
    // +---+
    // |  1|
    // |  2|
    // +---+
    ```
- fields inside array of `structs` can be accessed using dot-syntax, names and standard `Column` methods:

  ```
  df.select($"an_array_of_structs.foo").show

  // +----------+
  // |       foo|
  // +----------+
  // |[foo, bar]|
  // |[foz, baz]|
  // +----------+

  sqlContext.sql("SELECT an_array_of_structs[0].foo FROM df").show

  // +---+
  // |_c0|
  // +---+
  // |foo|
  // |foz|
  // +---+

  df.select($"an_array_of_structs.vals".getItem(1).getItem(1)).show

  // +------------------------------+
  // |an_array_of_structs.vals[1][1]|
  // +------------------------------+
  // |                           4.0|
  // |                           8.0|
  // +------------------------------+
  ```
- user defined types (UDTs) fields can be accessed using UDFs. See [Spark SQL referencing attributes of UDT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33747851/1560062) for details.

**Notes**:

- depending on a Spark version some of these methods can be available only with `HiveContext`. UDFs should work independent of version with both standard `SQLContext` and `HiveContext`.
- generally speaking nested values are a second class citizens. Not all typical operations are supported on nested fields. Depending on a context it could be better to flatten the schema and / or explode collections

  ```
  df.select(explode($"an_array_of_structs")).show

  // +--------------------+
  // |                 col|
  // +--------------------+
  // |[foo,1,WrappedArr...|
  // |[bar,2,WrappedArr...|
  // |[foz,3,WrappedArr...|
  // |[baz,4,WrappedArr...|
  // +--------------------+
  ```
- Dot syntax can be combined with wildcard character (`*`) to select (possibly multiple) fields without specifying names explicitly:

  ```
  df.select($"a_struct.*").show
  // +---+
  // |  x|
  // +---+
  // |  1|
  // |  2|
  // +---+
  ```
- JSON columns can be queried using `get_json_object` and `from_json` functions. See [How to query JSON data column using Spark DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34069282/) for details.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch all the elements in a struct array? Is something like this possible.. sqlContext.sql("SELECT an_array_of_structs[0].foo FROM df").show

Comment: How to do the same thing as `SELECT an_array_of_structs[0].foo FROM df` using code not spark sql? And is it supported to execute a UDF on an array of structs column(an_array_of_structs) using code? Like `SELECT max(an_array_of_structs.bar) FROM df` using code.

Comment: I get an error when trying to import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.transform. All the other imports seem to work, any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

Once You convert it to DF, u can simply fetch data as

```
  val rddRow= rdd.map(kv=>{
    val k = kv._1
    val v = kv._2
    Row(k, v)
  })

val myFld1 =  StructField("name", org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType, true)
val myFld2 =  StructField("map", org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType(StringType, StringType), true)
val arr = Array( myFld1, myFld2)
val schema = StructType( arr )
val rowrddDF = sqc.createDataFrame(rddRow, schema)
rowrddDF.registerTempTable("rowtbl")  
val rowrddDFFinal = rowrddDF.select(rowrddDF("map.one"))
or
val rowrddDFFinal = rowrddDF.select("map.one")
```

Comment: when I try this I get `error: value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Answer (score -1):

here was what I did and it worked

```
case class Test(name: String, m: Map[String, String])
val map = Map("hello" -> "world", "hey" -> "there")
val map2 = Map("hello" -> "people", "hey" -> "you")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(Test("first", map), Test("second", map2)))
val rdddf = rdd.toDF
rdddf.registerTempTable("mytable")
sqlContext.sql("select m.hello from mytable").show
```

Results

```
+------+
| hello|
+------+
| world|
|people|
+------+
```