# Derive multiple columns from a single column in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a DF with a huge parseable metadata as a single string column in a Dataframe, lets call it DFA, with ColmnA.

I would like to break this column, ColmnA into multiple columns thru a function, ClassXYZ = Func1(ColmnA). This function returns a class ClassXYZ, with multiple variables, and each of these variables now has to be mapped to new Column, such a ColmnA1, ColmnA2 etc.

How would I do such a transformation from 1 Dataframe to another with these additional columns by calling this Func1 just once, and not have to repeat-it to create all the columns.

Its easy to solve if I were to call this huge function every time to add a new column, but that what I wish to avoid.

Kindly please advise with a working or pseudo code.

Thanks

Sanjay

Answer (score 68):

Generally speaking what you want is not directly possible. UDF can return only a single column at the time. There are two different ways you can overcome this limitation:

1. Return a column of complex type. The most general solution is a `StructType` but you can consider `ArrayType` or `MapType` as well.

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

   val df = Seq(
     (1L, 3.0, "a"), (2L, -1.0, "b"), (3L, 0.0, "c")
   ).toDF("x", "y", "z")

   case class Foobar(foo: Double, bar: Double)

   val foobarUdf = udf((x: Long, y: Double, z: String) => 
     Foobar(x * y, z.head.toInt * y))

   val df1 = df.withColumn("foobar", foobarUdf($"x", $"y", $"z"))
   df1.show
   // +---+----+---+------------+
   // |  x|   y|  z|      foobar|
   // +---+----+---+------------+
   // |  1| 3.0|  a| [3.0,291.0]|
   // |  2|-1.0|  b|[-2.0,-98.0]|
   // |  3| 0.0|  c|   [0.0,0.0]|
   // +---+----+---+------------+

   df1.printSchema
   // root
   //  |-- x: long (nullable = false)
   //  |-- y: double (nullable = false)
   //  |-- z: string (nullable = true)
   //  |-- foobar: struct (nullable = true)
   //  |    |-- foo: double (nullable = false)
   //  |    |-- bar: double (nullable = false)
   ```

   This can be easily flattened later but usually there is no need for that.
2. Switch to RDD, reshape and rebuild DF:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

   def foobarFunc(x: Long, y: Double, z: String): Seq[Any] = 
     Seq(x * y, z.head.toInt * y)

   val schema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++
     Array(StructField("foo", DoubleType), StructField("bar", DoubleType)))

   val rows = df.rdd.map(r => Row.fromSeq(
     r.toSeq ++
     foobarFunc(r.getAs[Long]("x"), r.getAs[Double]("y"), r.getAs[String]("z"))))

   val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

   df2.show
   // +---+----+---+----+-----+
   // |  x|   y|  z| foo|  bar|
   // +---+----+---+----+-----+
   // |  1| 3.0|  a| 3.0|291.0|
   // |  2|-1.0|  b|-2.0|-98.0|
   // |  3| 0.0|  c| 0.0|  0.0|
   // +---+----+---+----+-----+
   ```

Comment: When you say "usually there's no for [flattening a column]", why is that? Or does spark allow most things that you do with top-level columns to also be done with hierarchical data (like `df1.foobar.foo`)?

Comment: @max Because simple `structs` can be used in pretty much any context when one would normally use flat structure (with simple dot syntax `fooobar.foo`). It doesn't apply to collection types though. You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33850490/1560062

Comment: You could try a different approach when assigning to the dataframe column, using the "withColumn" in the example is upper this:
     
    val df1 = df.withColumn("foo", foobarUdf($"x", $"y", $"z").getField("foo")).withColumn("bar", foobarUdf($"x", $"y", $"z").getField("bar"))

Now, the schema has 2 new columns: "foo" and "bar".

Answer (score 18):

Assume that after your function there will be a sequence of elements, giving an example as below:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("Mike,1986,Toronto", 30), ("Andre,1980,Ottawa", 36), ("jill,1989,London", 27))).toDF("infoComb", "age")
df.show
+------------------+---+
|          infoComb|age|
+------------------+---+
|Mike,1986,Toronto| 30|
| Andre,1980,Ottawa| 36|
|  jill,1989,London| 27|
+------------------+---+
```

now what you can do with this infoComb is that you can start split the string and get more columns with:

```
df.select(expr("(split(infoComb, ','))[0]").cast("string").as("name"), expr("(split(infoComb, ','))[1]").cast("integer").as("yearOfBorn"), expr("(split(infoComb, ','))[2]").cast("string").as("city"), $"age").show
+-----+----------+-------+---+
| name|yearOfBorn|   city|age|
+-----+----------+-------+---+
|Mike|      1986|Toronto| 30|
|Andre|      1980| Ottawa| 36|
| jill|      1989| London| 27|
+-----+----------+-------+---+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Couldn't you just say
df.select('infoComb.*', 'age')
The .* on a column name selects each field in the struct as a new column.

Answer (score 5):

If your resulting columns will be of the same length as the original one, you can create brand new columns with [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) function and by applying an udf. After this you can drop your original column, eg:

```
 val newDf = myDf.withColumn("newCol1", myFun(myDf("originalColumn")))
.withColumn("newCol2", myFun2(myDf("originalColumn"))
.drop(myDf("originalColumn"))
```

where myFun is an udf defined like this:

```
   def myFun= udf(
    (originalColumnContent : String) =>  {
      // do something with your original column content and return a new one
    }
  )
```

Comment: Hi Niemand, I appreciate your reply...but it does not solve the question...
in you code, you are calling the function "myDF" several times, whereas I would like that function to be called once, generate a class having multiple fields , and each field variable be returned as a new columns

Comment: Well I', afraid that I presented the only one possible way for know, I don't think that any other way exists, but hopefully I am wrong ;). Also not that I did not call myFun several times - you can call other functions like myFun2, myFun3 etc. to create columns that you need.

Answer (score 2):

I opted to create a function to flatten one column and then just call it simultaneously with the udf.

First define this:

```
implicit class DfOperations(df: DataFrame) {

  def flattenColumn(col: String) = {
    def addColumns(df: DataFrame, cols: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
      if (cols.isEmpty) df
      else addColumns(
        df.withColumn(col + "_" + cols.head, df(col + "." + cols.head)),
        cols.tail
      )
    }

    val field = df.select(col).schema.fields(0)
    val newCols = field.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields.map(x => x.name)

    addColumns(df, newCols).drop(col)
  }

  def withColumnMany(colName: String, col: Column) = {
    df.withColumn(colName, col).flattenColumn(colName)
  }

}
```

Then usage is very simple:

```
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: Int)

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (0),
  (1)
)).toDF("x")

val f = udf((x: Int) => MyClass(x*2,x*3))

df.withColumnMany("test", f($"x")).show()

//  +---+------+------+
//  |  x|test_a|test_b|
//  +---+------+------+
//  |  0|     0|     0|
//  |  1|     2|     3|
//  +---+------+------+
```

Comment: You don't have to do the whole withColumnMany thing. Just use select("select.*") to flatten it.

Answer (score -3):

This can be easily achieved by using pivot function

```
df4.groupBy("year").pivot("course").sum("earnings").collect()
```

Comment: I don't see "year", "course" or "earnings" in any of the answers or o.p... what  data frame are you talking about in this very terse answer (not)?