# Apache Spark -- Assign the result of UDF to multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm using pyspark, loading a large csv file into a dataframe with spark-csv, and as a pre-processing step I need to apply a variety of operations to the data available in one of the columns (that contains a json string). That will return X values, each of which needs to be stored in their own separate column.

That functionality will be implemented in a UDF. However, I am not sure how to return a list of values from that UDF and feed these into individual columns. Below is a simple example:

```
(...)
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def udf_test(n):
    return [n/2, n%2]

test_udf=udf(udf_test)


df.select('amount','trans_date').withColumn("test", test_udf("amount")).show(4)
```

That produces the following:

```
+------+----------+--------------------+
|amount|trans_date|                test|
+------+----------+--------------------+
|  28.0|2016-02-07|         [14.0, 0.0]|
| 31.01|2016-02-07|[15.5050001144409...|
| 13.41|2016-02-04|[6.70499992370605...|
| 307.7|2015-02-17|[153.850006103515...|
| 22.09|2016-02-05|[11.0450000762939...|
+------+----------+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

What would be the best way to store the two (in this example) values being returned by the udf on separate columns? Right now they are being typed as strings:

```
df.select('amount','trans_date').withColumn("test", test_udf("amount")).printSchema()

root
 |-- amount: float (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It is not possible to create multiple top level columns from a single UDF call but you can create a new `struct`. It requires an UDF with specified `returnType`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("foo", FloatType(), False),
    StructField("bar", FloatType(), False)
])

def udf_test(n):
    return (n / 2, n % 2) if n and n != 0.0 else (float('nan'), float('nan'))

test_udf = udf(udf_test, schema)
df = sc.parallelize([(1, 2.0), (2, 3.0)]).toDF(["x", "y"])

foobars = df.select(test_udf("y").alias("foobar"))
foobars.printSchema()
## root
##  |-- foobar: struct (nullable = true)
##  |    |-- foo: float (nullable = false)
##  |    |-- bar: float (nullable = false)
```

You further flatten the schema with simple `select`:

```
foobars.select("foobar.foo", "foobar.bar").show()
## +---+---+
## |foo|bar|
## +---+---+
## |1.0|0.0|
## |1.5|1.0|
## +---+---+
```

See also [Derive multiple columns from a single column in a Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32196207/1560062)

Comment: Fantastic! This works very well for what I needed. I was most of the way there, but was feeding the StructType schema incorrectly to the udf, which was causing my new column to end up as StringType instead. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks!! This was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: You could also do `foobars.select("foobar.*")` instead of naming each column individually.

Comment: You can also "mix" both original columns and these from the UDF, in a two step process:   `df.select("x", test_udf("y").alias("foobar")).select("x", "foobar.*")`

Comment: `from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType`

Comment: To add only the new columns to an existing dataframe, try

df.withColumn('foobar', test_udf('y')).select(
  df.columns + [df['foobar.%s' % c.name] for c in schema]
)

Answer (score 2):

you can use flatMap to get the column the desired dataframe in one go

```
df=df.withColumn('udf_results',udf)  
df4=df.select('udf_results').rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).toDF(schema=your_new_schema)
```