# Pyspark UDF that returns multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read a fixed width file using pyspark. The format of the file can be easily parsed using python's struct module. So, my idea was to define an udf that uses `struct.unpack`, working the values and returning multiple columns to the original data frame. Unfortunately, it seems it doesn't work for some obscure (to me) reason.

The structure of the text file is as follow:

```
CD  EUR  0025800202878
CD  EUR  0025800203059
CD  EUR  0025800203070
CD  EUR  0025800203085
CD  EUR  0025800203110
```

My code, instead, is:

```py
# libraries import and spark session setup omitted

FMT_STRING='3sx3sx4s3s7sx'
schema = StructType([
        StructField('type', StringType(), False),
        StructField('value', StringType(), False),
        StructField('group', LongType(), False),
        StructField('cat', LongType(), False),
        StructField('account', LongType(), False)
])

def unpacker(x):
    values =  struct.unpack(FMT_STRING, x.encode('utf-8'))

    return Row('tye', 'value', 'group', 'cat', 'account')(
        values[0].decode('utf-8').strip(),
        values[1].decode('utf-8').strip(),
        int(values[2].decode('utf-8').strip()),
        int(values[3].decode('utf-8').strip()),
        int(values[4].decode('utf-8').strip())
    )

unpacker_udf = F.udf(unpacker, schema)

data = spark.read.format('text').load('example_file.txt')
data = data.withColumn('results', unpacker_udf(F.col('value')))
data.show()

# Another approach is to do:
#
# data = spark.read.format('text').load('example_file.txt')
# data2 = data.select(unpacker_udf('value').alias('results'))
# data2.printSchema()
# ...
# the schema is shown
#
# data2.show()
# ...
# the same exception is thrown
```

Once the code reach the last line, I get this error:

```
...
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o128.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6) (xyz.abc executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
...
```

From my understanding, it seems the python function is not passed to the JVM, but I'm not able to figure out where the problem is.

I've also followed the approach suggested in [Apache Spark -- Assign the result of UDF to multiple dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322764/apache-spark-assign-the-result-of-udf-to-multiple-dataframe-columns) . In that case my code read slightly different (see the comment in the code), but the outcome is the same error.

EDIT: After inspection of the code in the answer at the previous link, it too returns the same error I'm getting with my approach