# How to get keys and values from MapType column in SparkSQL DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have data in a parquet file which has 2 fields: `object_id: String` and `alpha: Map<>`.

It is read into a data frame in sparkSQL and the schema looks like this:

```
scala> alphaDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- object_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ALPHA: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I am using Spark 2.0 and I am trying to create a new data frame in which columns need to be `object_id` plus keys of the `ALPHA` map as in `object_id, key1, key2, key2, ...`

I was first trying to see if I could at least access the map like this:

```
scala> alphaDF.map(a => a(0)).collect()
<console>:32: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.
Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are 
supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other
types will be added in future releases.
   alphaDF.map(a => a(0)).collect()
```

but unfortunately I can't seem to be able to figure out how to access the keys of the map.

Can someone please show me a way to get the `object_id` plus map keys as column names and map values as respective values in a new dataframe?

Comment: There isnt a super clean way to do this I dont think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33345698/2661491

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.3**

You can simplify the process using `map_keys` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map_keys
```

There is also `map_values` function, but it won't be directly useful here.

**Spark < 2.3**

General method can be expressed in a few steps. First required imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

and example data:

```
val ds = Seq(
  (1, Map("foo" -> (1, "a"), "bar" -> (2, "b"))),
  (2, Map("foo" -> (3, "c"))),
  (3, Map("bar" -> (4, "d")))
).toDF("id", "alpha")
```

To extract keys we can use UDF (Spark < 2.3)

```
val map_keys = udf[Seq[String], Map[String, Row]](_.keys.toSeq)
```

or built-in functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map_keys

val keysDF = df.select(map_keys($"alpha"))
```

Find distinct ones:

```
val distinctKeys = keysDF.as[Seq[String]].flatMap(identity).distinct
  .collect.sorted
```

You can also generalize `keys` extraction with `explode`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

val distinctKeys = df
  // Flatten the column into key, value columns
 .select(explode($"alpha"))
 .select($"key")
 .as[String].distinct
 .collect.sorted
```

And `select`:

```
ds.select($"id" +: distinctKeys.map(x => $"alpha".getItem(x).alias(x)): _*)
```

Comment: And how to implement this in PySpaek?

Answer (score 4):

And if you are in PySpark, I just find an easy implementation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import map_keys

alphaDF.select(map_keys("ALPHA").alias("keys")).show()
```

You can check details in [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=ntile#pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys)