# How to get keys and values from MapType column in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to replicate the solution of this question in PySpark (Spark < 2.3, so no map_keys):
[How to get keys and values from MapType column in SparkSQL DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602606/how-to-get-keys-and-values-from-maptype-column-in-sparksql-dataframe)
Below is my code (same df of the linked question above):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

distinctKeys = df\
  .select(F.explode("alpha"))\
  .select("key")\
  .distinct()\
  .rdd

df.select("id", distinctKeys.map(lambda x: "alpha".getItem(x).alias(x))
```

However, this code gives the error: `AttributeError: 'PipelineRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create distinctKeys as a list of strings, then use list comprehension to set each key on its own column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# generate a list of distinct keys from the MapType column
distinctKeys = df.select(F.explode("alpha")).agg(F.collect_set("key").alias('keys')).first().keys
# or use your existing method
# distinctKeys = [ d.key for d in df.select(F.explode("alpha")).select("key").distinct().collect() ]

df_new = df.select("id", *[ F.col("alpha")[k].alias(k) for k in distinctKeys ])
```