# Generate dynamic header using Scala case class for Spark Table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, case-class

```
I have an existing case class having many fields 
case class output {
   userId : String, 
   timeStamp: String, 
   ...
}
And I am using it to generate header for a spark job like this.

--------------------
userId  | timeStamp|
-------------------- 
1         2324444444
2         2334445556

Now i want to add more columns to this and these column will be come from 
 map(attributeName, attributeValue) as attributeNames. So my question 
 is how can I add map to case class and then how can i use map key as 
 column value to generate dynamic columns. After this my final output 
 should be like 

----------------------------------------------------
userId  | timeStamp| attributeName1 | attributeName2
----------------------------------------------------
1         2324444444|               | 
2         2334445554|               |
```

Comment: check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869134/pyspark-converting-a-column-of-type-map-to-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe

Comment: Actually, I want to know that can i do it using case class or not. If yes, then how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
 case class output {
       userId : String, 
       timeStamp: String,
       keyvalues: Map, 
       ...
    }
    import spark.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val df = spark.read.textFile(inputlocation).as[output]
    val keysDF = df.select(explode(map_keys($"keyvalues"))).distinct()
    val keys = keysDF.collect().map(f=>f.get(0)).map(f=>col("keyvalues").getItem(f).as(f.toString))
    df.select(col("userId") +: keyCols:_*)
```

or you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602606/how-to-get-keys-and-values-from-maptype-column-in-sparksql-dataframe) for other ways todo.