# Spark extract values from string and assign as column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Need help in parsing a string, where it contains values for each attribute. below is my sample string...

```
Type=<Series VR> Model=<1Ac4> ID=<34> conn seq=<2>
Type=<SeriesX> Model=<12Q3> ID=<231> conn seq=<3423123>
```

from the above, I have to generate the columns with values as below.

```
Type | Model | Id | conn seq
----------------------------
Series VR | 1Ac4 | 34 | 2
SeriesX | 12Q3 | 231 | 3423123
```

not sure of how to parse it by regex/split and using withColumn().

help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample, you can convert the String into Map using SparkSQL function [str_to_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map) and then select values from the desired map keys(below code assumed the StringType column name is `value`):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

keys = ['Type', 'Model', 'ID', 'conn seq']

df.withColumn("m", F.expr("str_to_map(value, '> *', '=<')")) \
    .select("*", *[ F.col('m')[k].alias(k) for k in keys ]) \
    .show()
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+---+--------+
|               value|                   m|     Type|Model| ID|conn seq|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+---+--------+
|Type=<Series VR> ...|[Type -> Series V...|Series VR| 1Ac4| 34|       2|
|Type=<SeriesX> Mo...|[Type -> SeriesX,...|  SeriesX| 12Q3|231| 3423123|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+---+--------+
```

**Notes:** Here we use the regex pattern `> *` to split pairs and pattern `=<` to split key/value. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40603522/9510729) if `keys` of the Map are dynamic and not able to predefined, just make sure to filter out the EMPTY key.

**Edit:** Based on comments, to do case-insensitive search on map keys. for **Spark 2.3**, we can use [pandas_udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) to preprocess the `value` column before using str_to_map function:

1. setup the regex pattern for matched keys(in capturing group-1). here we use `(?i)` to set up case-insensitive match, and add two anchors `\b` and `(?==)`, so that the matched sub-strings must have a word boundary to the left and followed by an `=` mark to the right.

   ```
   ptn = "(?i)\\b({})(?==)".format('|'.join(keys))
   print(ptn)
   #(?i)\b(Type|Model|ID|conn seq)(?==)
   ```
2. set up pandas_udf so we can use [Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) and set a callback(lowercase $1) as replacement:

   ```
   lower_keys = F.pandas_udf(lambda s: s.str.replace(ptn, lambda m: m.group(1).lower()), "string")
   ```
3. convert all matched keys to lowercase:

   ```
   df1 = df.withColumn('value', lower_keys('value'))
   +-------------------------------------------------------+
   |value                                                  |
   +-------------------------------------------------------+
   |type=<Series VR> model=<1Ac4> id=<34> conn seq=<2>     |
   |type=<SeriesX> model=<12Q3> id=<231> conn seq=<3423123>|
   +-------------------------------------------------------+
   ```
4. use str_to_map to create map, and then use `k.lower()` as keys to find their corresponding values.

   ```
   df1.withColumn("m", F.expr("str_to_map(value, '> *', '=<')")) \
       .select("*", *[ F.col('m')[k.lower()].alias(k) for k in keys ]) \
       .show()
   ```

**Note:** in case you can use **Spark 3.0+** in the future, skip the above steps and use [transform_keys](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform_keys) function instead:

```
df.withColumn("m", F.expr("str_to_map(value, '> *', '=<')")) \
    .withColumn("m", F.expr("transform_keys(m, (k,v) -> lower(k))")) \
    .select("*", *[ F.col('m')[k.lower()].alias(k) for k in keys ]) \
    .show()
```

For **Spark 2.4+**, replace `transform_keys(...)` with the following:

```
map_from_entries(transform(map_keys(m), k -> (lower(k), m[k])))
```

Comment: along with that String, there are other columns in the DF. how to fetch those as well along with these new columns from the map. thanks

Comment: i tried that, except I want to check whether to keep * in the second select without specifying all the column names.

Comment: gotcha. i realizes, missed the '*' infront of the list . it worked. thanks for your quick help.:) @jxc

Comment: HI @jxc.. quick help. how to do the case insensitive search for the keys... like making lower or upper on the map keys. thanks

Comment: @marc, for Spark 3.0+, we can use `transform_keys` to convert all map keys to lower-case, we can do the similar to Spark 2.4+. what is your spark version?

Comment: using 2.3 currently :(. can you let me know on how to do it in 2.3 or integrating the transform_keys in the above solution for 2.4. thanks

Comment: for spark 2.3, the map/array functions are limited, but I think we can use pandas_udf, let me do some testing and then update the post.

Comment: upgraded my local to 2.4. can you help me out on how to do it

Comment: @marc, check the end of my updated post, just post-process the map, say `.withColumn("m", F.expr("map_from_entries(transform(map_keys(m), k -> (lower(k), m[k])))"))`

Comment: n/p, just let me know for any issues.

Comment: Hi  need quick help. my spark is 2.3 and when trying your code, getting 'PyArrow >=0.8.0' needs to be installed and it's out of my scope to pip it, as I am not sudo.  i am trying to use map_keys solution, and getting 'extraneous input '>' expecting  .... ==\ntransform_keys(m, (k,v) -> lower(k))' error.. is this due to syntax or needed 2.4 version ? @jxc

Comment: then try using udf: `lower_keys = F.udf(lambda x: re.sub(ptn, lambda m: m.group(1).lower(),x) if x else x, "string")`, make sure to `import re` and pre-compile the regex pattern using: `ptn = re.compile(r"(?i)\\b({})(?==)".format('|'.join(keys)))`.. as mentioned in the post, transform_keys requires Spark 3.0+.

Comment: Hi @jxc. sorry to bother. how to extract the same string wich have only '=' , instead of '=<>' . my input string is " ...... Type=Series VRsomeTest  Model=1Ac4 ID=4 sometesthere" . I need to have columns Type, Model, ID. any help

Comment: Hi, @marc, you can adjust the pariDelim and keyValueDelim in str_to_map function, for example: `df.withColumn("m", F.expr("str_to_map(value,'(?i) +(?=type|model|id|conn seq)','=')"))`. where we use lookahead anchor `(?=..)` to set pairDelim to SPACE only followed by the keys. you can dynamically generate this using python String-format method, say: `F.expr("str_to_map(value,'(?i) +(?={})','=')".format('|'.join(keys)))`. notice that I removed the non-capturing group from the regex pattern in the code of my deleted comment.

Comment: Hi @jxc, things are getting little tricky on my end. in the value column, sometimes I will be getting data with =<>, like key=<value> and sometimes it will be without <> , like key=value.

Comment: @marc, can you add a new question with sample texts? it's a little too late right now and I will have to check this tomorrow.

Comment: sure. thanks for all the help. you went beyond the way to help me out. really appreciate it. good night. @jxc

Comment: Hello @jxc. created a new question. can you please take a look if possible?. thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704020/spark-extract-columns-from-string