# spark extract columns from string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Need help in parsing a string, where it contains values for each attribute. below is my sample string...

```
otherPartofString Name=<Series VR> Type=<1Ac4> SqVal=<34> conn ID=<2>
```

sometimes, the string can include other values with a different delimiter like

```
otherPartofString Name=<Series X> Type=<1B3> SqVal=<34> conn ID=<2> conn Loc=sfo dest=chc bridge otherpartofString..
```

the output columns will be

```
Name      | Type | SqVal | ID | Loc  | dest 
-------------------------------------------
Series VR | 1Ac4 | 34    | 2  | null | null
Series X  | 1B3  | 34    | 2  | sfo  | chc
```

Comment: Is the enclosing `< >` used to contain values having SPACEs? otherwise it will be hard to separate `dest=chc` with `bridge otherpartofString`?  we will either need some pre-processing or post-processing on the last capturing field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed, to use [str_to_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map) function on your sample data, we can setup *pairDelim* and *keyValueDelim* to the following:

```
pairDelim: '(?i)>? *(?=Name|Type|SqVal|conn ID|conn Loc|dest|$)'
keyValueDelim: '=<?'
```

Where **pariDelim** is case-insensitive `(?i)` with an optional `>` followed by zero or more SPACEs, then followed by one of the pre-defined keys (we use `'|'.join(keys)` to generate it dynamically) or the end of string anchor `$`.  **keyValueDelim** is an '=' with an optional `<`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([                                               
   ("otherPartofString Name=<Series VR> Type=<1Ac4> SqVal=<34> conn ID=<2>",),   
   ("otherPartofString Name=<Series X> Type=<1B3> SqVal=<34> conn ID=<2> conn Loc=sfo dest=chc bridge otherpartofString..",)
],["value"])

keys = ["Name", "Type", "SqVal", "conn ID", "conn Loc", "dest"]

# add the following conf for Spark 3.0 to overcome duplicate map key ERROR
#spark.conf.set("spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy", "LAST_WIN")

df.withColumn("m", F.expr("str_to_map(value, '(?i)>? *(?={}|$)', '=<?')".format('|'.join(keys)))) \
    .select([F.col('m')[k].alias(k) for k in keys]) \
    .show()
+---------+----+-----+-------+--------+--------------------+
|     Name|Type|SqVal|conn ID|conn Loc|                dest|
+---------+----+-----+-------+--------+--------------------+
|Series VR|1Ac4|   34|      2|    null|                null|
| Series X| 1B3|   34|      2|     sfo|chc bridge otherp...|
+---------+----+-----+-------+--------+--------------------+
```

We will need to do some post-processing to the values of the last mapped-key, since there is no anchor or pattern to distinguish them from other unrelated text (this could be a problem as it might happen on any keys), please let me know if you can specify any pattern.

**Edit:** If using map is less efficient for case-insensitive search since it requires some expensive pre-processing, try the following:

```
ptn = '|'.join(keys)
df.select("*", *[F.regexp_extract('value', r'(?i)\b{0}=<?([^=>]+?)>? *(?={1}|$)'.format(k,ptn), 1).alias(k) for k in keys]).show()
```

In case the angle brackets `<` and `>` are used only when values or their next adjacent key contain any non-word chars, it can be simplified with some pre-processing:

```
df.withColumn('value', F.regexp_replace('value','=(\w+)','=<$1>')) \
    .select("*", *[F.regexp_extract('value', r'(?i)\b{0}=<([^>]+)>'.format(k), 1).alias(k) for k in keys]) \
    .show()
```

**Edit-2:** added a dictionary to handle key aliases:

```
keys = ["Name", "Type", "SqVal", "ID", "Loc", "dest"]

# aliases are case-insensitive and added only if exist
key_aliases = {
    'Type': [ 'ThisType', 'AnyName' ],
    'ID': ['conn ID'],
    'Loc': ['conn Loc']
}

# set up regex pattern for each key differently
key_ptns = [ (k, '|'.join([k, *key_aliases[k]]) if k in key_aliases else k) for k in keys ]  
#[('Name', 'Name'),
# ('Type', 'Type|ThisType|AnyName'),
# ('SqVal', 'SqVal'),
# ('ID', 'ID|conn ID'),
# ('Loc', 'Loc|conn Loc'),
# ('dest', 'dest')]  

df.withColumn('value', F.regexp_replace('value','=(\w+)','=<$1>')) \
    .select("*", *[F.regexp_extract('value', r'(?i)\b(?:{0})=<([^>]+)>'.format(p), 1).alias(k) for k,p in key_ptns]) \
    .show()
+--------------------+---------+----+-----+---+---+----+
|               value|     Name|Type|SqVal| ID|Loc|dest|
+--------------------+---------+----+-----+---+---+----+
|otherPartofString...|Series VR|1Ac4|   34|  2|   |    |
|otherPartofString...| Series X| 1B3|   34|  2|sfo| chc|
+--------------------+---------+----+-----+---+---+----+
```

Comment: BTW. since you are using Spark 2.3 with the case-insensitive search, have issue with pandas_udf. it's probably better choice to use regex_extract to to get values of these keys as shown in one of your previous questions.

Comment: Hi @jxc..sorry for late reply.  suppose if there the string is 'Name=<Series VR> Location Type=<1Ac4>' i.e., if there is non <=> values, str_to_map is failing.. but the last solution you have provided using 'regexp_extract' is working as expected. thanks again for the detailed explanation and helping me out all the way. you are the best :)

Comment: @marc, glad it helps, the function `str_to_map` has limitations, there should not be any gap between pairs, key/values other than the two delimiters, in your example, you might have to set key=`Location Type` instead of `Type`. and map is also not efficient when dealing with case-insensitive search (require some post or pre-processing).

Comment: BTW. can you upvote and accept my answer, have a good night! :)

Comment: sorry.. forgot accepting. thanks again and have a good night @jxc :)

Comment: Hello @jxc. Hope you r good.  I have a column which may contain a value like 'Name=<SeriesX>' or may be like  'ThisisName=<Series X>' . I want to extract the column Name with its value SeriesX. Can you please help?

Comment: hi @marc, you can remove `\b` from the pattern, but this will match also `otherName`, `otherType` etc. If only `Thisis` is allowed, use pattern `r'(?i)\b(?:|Thisis){0}=<([^>]+)>'.format(k)`, notice we just insert `(?:|Thisis)` after `\b`, so this will match Name, ThisisName, ThisisType, but not OtherName, OtherType etc. `\b` is the regex anchor for word-boundary

Comment: Hi @jxc. Good Morning. 'Thisis' is just an example. in place of that, there can be any other string combined with the column name. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @marc, check Edit-2 in the updated post. could be enough to use a dictionary to handle aliases for the same name.

Comment: Howdy @jxc ? need your help. can you please take a look and can you guide me on how to do, if you can..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921362/pyspark-get-related-records-from-its-array-object-values

Comment: @marc, I saw your question. I think you probably need grameframe or if the max depth of the hierarchy is known and a small number, do some recursive self-joins? I requested reopen your question and would like to see if someone can come up with a good solution. BTW. what's your spark version, 2.4+ or below?

Comment: Hello @jxc. i created a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921362/pyspark-get-related-records-from-its-array-object-values. my spark is 2.3. the max depth will be mostly like 2-4

Comment: Hi and hope you are doing good/staying safe. I need your help with one of my req and got struck. Please help if you can and appreciate your time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528350/pyspark-convert-rows-to-columns. @jxc