# PySpark get related records from its array object values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that has an ID column and along with other columns, it has an array column that contains the IDs of its related records, as its value.

example dataframe will be of

```
ID | NAME | RELATED_IDLIST
--------------------------
123 | mike | [345,456]
345 | alen | [789]
456 | sam  | [789,999]
789 | marc | [111]
555 | dan  | [333]
```

From the above, I need to append all the related child Id's to the array column of the parent ID. The resultant DF should be like

```
ID | NAME | RELATED_IDLIST
 --------------------------
 123 | mike | [345,456,789,999,111]
 345 | alen | [789,111]
 456 | sam  | [789,999,111]
 789 | marc | [111]
 555 | dan  | [333]
```

need help on how to do it. thanks

Comment: Hello @Srinivas. I am using 2.3. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this task is to do *self* **leftjoin**, update the *RELATED_IDLIST*, do this several iterations until some conditions satisfy (this works only when the max-depth of the whole hierarchy is small). For **Spark 2.3**, we can convert the ArrayType column into a comma-delimitered StringType column, use SQL builtin function [find_in_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#find_in_set) and a new column `PROCESSED_IDLIST` to set up the join-conditions, see below for the main logic:

**Functions:**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

# define a function which takes a dataframe as input, does a self left-join and then return another 
# dataframe with exactly the same schema as the input dataframe. do the same repeatly until some conditions satisfy
def recursive_join(d, max_iter=10):
  # function to find direct child-IDs and merge into RELATED_IDLIST
  def find_child_idlist(_df):
    return _df.alias('d1').join(
        _df.alias('d2'), 
        F.expr("find_in_set(d2.ID,d1.RELATED_IDLIST)>0 AND find_in_set(d2.ID,d1.PROCESSED_IDLIST)<1"),
        "left"
      ).groupby("d1.ID", "d1.NAME").agg(
        F.expr("""
          /* combine d1.RELATED_IDLIST with all matched entries from collect_set(d2.RELATED_IDLIST)
           * and remove trailing comma from when all d2.RELATED_IDLIST are NULL */
          trim(TRAILING ',' FROM
              concat_ws(",", first(d1.RELATED_IDLIST), concat_ws(",", collect_list(d2.RELATED_IDLIST)))
          ) as RELATED_IDLIST"""),
        F.expr("first(d1.RELATED_IDLIST) as PROCESSED_IDLIST")
    )
  # below the main code logic
  d = find_child_idlist(d).persist()
  if (d.filter("RELATED_IDLIST!=PROCESSED_IDLIST").count() > 0) & (max_iter > 1):
    d = recursive_join(d, max_iter-1)
  return d

# define pandas_udf to remove duplicate from an ArrayType column
get_uniq = F.pandas_udf(lambda s: pd.Series([ list(set(x)) for x in s ]), "array<int>")
```

**Where:**

1. in the function `find_child_idlist()`, the left-join must satisfy the following two conditions:

   - *d2.ID* is in *d1.RELATED_IDLIST*:    `find_in_set(d2.ID,d1.RELATED_IDLIST)>0`
   - *d2.ID* not in *d1.PROCESSED_IDLIST*: `find_in_set(d2.ID,d1.PROCESSED_IDLIST)<1`
2. quit the recursive_join when no row satisfying `RELATED_IDLIST!=PROCESSED_IDLIST` or `max_iter > 1`

**Processing:**

1. set up dataframe:

   ```
   df = spark.createDataFrame([
     (123, "mike", [345,456]), (345, "alen", [789]), (456, "sam", [789,999]),
     (789, "marc", [111]), (555, "dan", [333])
   ],["ID", "NAME", "RELATED_IDLIST"])
   ```
2. add a new column `PROCESSED_IDLIST` to save `RELATED_IDLIST` in the previous join, and do `recursive_join()`

   ```
   df1 = df.withColumn('RELATED_IDLIST', F.concat_ws(',','RELATED_IDLIST')) \
       .withColumn('PROCESSED_IDLIST', F.col('ID'))

   df_new = recursive_join(df1, 5)
   df_new.show(10,0)
   +---+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
   |ID |NAME|RELATED_IDLIST         |PROCESSED_IDLIST       |
   +---+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
   |555|dan |333                    |333                    |
   |789|marc|111                    |111                    |
   |345|alen|789,111                |789,111                |
   |123|mike|345,456,789,789,999,111|345,456,789,789,999,111|
   |456|sam |789,999,111            |789,999,111            |
   +---+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
   ```
3. split `RELATED_IDLIST` into array of integers and then use pandas_udf function to drop duplicate array elements:

   ```
   df_new.withColumn("RELATED_IDLIST", get_uniq(F.split('RELATED_IDLIST', ',').cast('array<int>'))).show(10,0)
   +---+----+-------------------------+-----------------------+
   |ID |NAME|RELATED_IDLIST           |PROCESSED_IDLIST       |
   +---+----+-------------------------+-----------------------+
   |555|dan |[333]                    |333                    |
   |789|marc|[111]                    |111                    |
   |345|alen|[789, 111]               |789,111                |
   |123|mike|[999, 456, 111, 789, 345]|345,456,789,789,999,111|
   |456|sam |[111, 789, 999]          |789,999,111            |
   +---+----+-------------------------+-----------------------+
   ```

Comment: for spark 2.4+, we can take the same logic but replace `find_in_set` with `array_contains` , and use `array_union`, `array_remove`, `flatten` etc to rebuild RELATED_IDLIST and there is no need to drop duplicates.

Comment: hi, @marc, I adjusted some code logic so that the `ID` is excluded from PROCESSED_IDLIST at the beginning instead of removing it using regexp_replace. This should also help find the cases when ID itself is in the RELATED_LIST of its child. let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @jxc. sorry for the late reply (been out). i implemented with a different solution, using the self joins. will test your code. thank you so much for helping me every time. sorry again for the late reply.

Comment: @marc, no worry and hope you had a great vacation. BTW. you might just do the same self-join in a iterative way and there is no need to count and persist the intermediate dataframe in every iteration which could be expensive. stay safe and happy holiday!

Comment: Hi and hope you are doing good/staying safe. I need your help with one of my req and got struck. Please help if you can and appreciate your time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528350/pyspark-convert-rows-to-columns @jxc

Comment: Hi, @marc, sorry for the late reply, I am very busy this year and don't have enough time to follow up the SO questions. for your question, what have you tried so far with the pivot? IMO, you can always use list-comprehension to replace pivot if that's what you want???

Comment: Hello. completely understood and thanks for taking a look. I was able to figure out the solution and will post the answer to it. thanks again and have a good day @jxc. stay safe

Comment: @marc, if I understood your question correctly, it looks like a typical case of using dense_rank function to create a list of pivot values (instead of using ID column). the resulting df will still be handled with pivot function though. I can add an answer to your post if needed:). have a great day and stay safe :)

Comment: i was able to figure out the answer. i did the rank and then used the collect_list for it. for pivoting, I used the map function on the columns required. thanks for helping. :) @jxc

Comment: @marc, I added an answer to address the method I mentioned above. it's ideal to use dense_rank instead of rank so that we can pre-define the list to pivot on. this should work unless some customer have big number of distinct IDs (N in the code). Also, when using collect_list, we will have to sort_array based on the `order` field. since there is no arrays_zip function under spark 2.3, so I guess you will have to use some sort of UDF??  :) have a good day....

Comment: Hello @JXC.. thanks for making time to answer my question. really appreciate it. I did post my answer as well. thanks for your help. take care  :)

Comment: @marc, you are very welcome and glad you have had a solution. just drop me a line if needed, I'll be more than happy to help with my knowledge. stay well and be happy:)

Comment: thank you for your kindness to help and share your knowledge.  will reach out for any help. thanks again and god bless.

Comment: Hello..hope you are doing good. I have a complex new use case and I need your help. Is there any way we can connect directly, to explain ?