# Spark UDF returning more than one item

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible for a spark UDF to return more than one value? If so how are the individual items accessed in the dataframes API.

Comment: UDFs can only return single column values. These values can be collections or tuples but they can't be multiple values. If you really need to you can return a tuple and then split it using a command like `$"colname_1"`, `$"colname_2"` etc

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196207/derive-multiple-columns-from-a-single-column-in-a-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options:

- Return a `Seq` of items of the same type to create `array` column.

  ```
  udf(() => Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
  ```
- Return a `Map`:

  ```
  udf(() => Map("x" -> 1.0, "y" -> -1.0))
  ```
- Return a product (tuple or an instance of a case class) to create `struct` column.

  ```
  udf(() => (1.0, "foo", 5))
  ```

Comment: Thanks. How about the second part of the question? My current solution is to add an additional select op to access individual items. Is there another way to flatten the returned values?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **struct** and **array** method to achieve this.

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981218/2323639) for a very clean and easy answer by [@ramesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5880706/ramesh-maharjan)