# How to use UDF to return multiple columns?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to create a UDF which would return the set of columns?

I.e. having a data frame as follows:

```
| Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature 3 |
| 1.3      | 3.4      | 4.5       |
```

Now I would like to extract a new feature, which can be described as a vector of let's say two elements (e.g. as seen in a linear regression - slope and offset). Desired dataset shall look as follows:

```
| Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature 3 | Slope | Offset |
| 1.3      | 3.4      | 4.5       | 0.5   | 3      |
```

Is it possible to create multiple columns with single UDF or do I need to follow the rule: "single column per single UDF"?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Struct method**

You can define the `udf` function as

```
def myFunc: (String => (String, String)) = { s => (s.toLowerCase, s.toUpperCase)}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)
```

and use `.*` as

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", myUDF(df("Feature2"))).select("Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature 3", "newCol.*")
```

I have returned `Tuple2` for testing purpose (higher order tuples can be used according to how many multiple columns are required) from `udf` function and it would be treated as `struct` column. Then you can use `.*` to select all the elements in separate columns and finally rename them.

You should have output as

```
+--------+--------+---------+---+---+
|Feature1|Feature2|Feature 3|_1 |_2 |
+--------+--------+---------+---+---+
|1.3     |3.4     |4.5      |3.4|3.4|
+--------+--------+---------+---+---+
```

You can rename `_1` and `_2`

**Array method**

`udf` function should return an `array`

```
def myFunc: (String => Array[String]) = { s => Array("s".toLowerCase, s.toUpperCase)}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)
```

And the you can select elements of the `array` and use `alias` to rename them

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", myUDF(df("Feature2"))).select($"Feature1", $"Feature2", $"Feature 3", $"newCol"(0).as("Slope"), $"newCol"(1).as("Offset"))
```

You should have

```
+--------+--------+---------+-----+------+
|Feature1|Feature2|Feature 3|Slope|Offset|
+--------+--------+---------+-----+------+
|1.3     |3.4     |4.5      |s    |3.4   |
+--------+--------+---------+-----+------+
```

Comment: That's a great solution, thanks! Another question is how many times is the UDF called? I added counter to count the number of calls and in the code above the UDF is called 3 times. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I saw your other answer on processing all columns in `df`, and combined with this, they offer a great solution.However, I am stuck at using the return value from the `UDF` to modify multiple columns using `withColumn` which only takes one column name at a time. Would you know of a workaround?

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can return the case class:

```
case class NewFeatures(slope: Double, offset: Int)

val getNewFeatures = udf { s: String =>
      NewFeatures(???, ???)
    }

df
  .withColumn("newF", getNewFeatures($"Feature1"))
  .select($"Feature1", $"Feature2", $"Feature3", $"newF.slope", $"newF.offset")
```

Answer (score 3):

I miss an explanation about how to assign the multiples values in the case class to several columns in the dataframe.

So, in summary, a complete example in Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df = Seq((1L, 3.0, "a"), (2L, -1.0, "b"), (3L, 0.0, "c")).toDF("x", "y", "z")

case class Foobar(foo: Double, bar: Double)

val foobarUdf = udf((x: Long, y: Double, z: String) => 
  Foobar(x * y, z.head.toInt * y))

val df1 = df.withColumn("foo", foobarUdf($"x", $"y", $"z").getField("foo")).withColumn("bar", foobarUdf($"x", $"y", $"z").getField("bar"))
```

If you check the schema of the df1 dataframe, you'll get

```
scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- x: long (nullable = false)
 |-- y: double (nullable = false)
 |-- z: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: double (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: double (nullable = true)
```