# Spark UDF to split a column value to multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a dataframe column called 'description' value in the below format

```
ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX STORE NAME ABC TYPE1
```

I will like to parse it into different 3 columns like below

```
|  mode |  type  |  store       |  description                           |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  ABC  |  TYPE1 |  STORE NAME  | ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX STORE NAME ABC TYPE1  |
```

I tried the method suggested in the like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979440/spark-udf-outputing-multiple-columns). It works for simple UDF function but not for the function I have written. The challenge is that the value of store could be more 2 words or no fixed number of words.

```
def myFunc1: (String => (String, String, String)) = { description =>
      var descripe = description.split(" ")
      val type = descripe(descripe.size - 1)
      descripe = description.substring(description.indexOf("ABC") + 4, description.lastIndexOf("ABC")).split(" ")
      val mode = descripe(0)
      descripe(0) = ""
      val store = descripe.mkString(" ").trim
      (mode, store, type)
    }

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("mode", StringType, true),
  StructField("store", StringType, true),
  StructField("type", StringType, true)
))

val myUDF = udf(myFunc1, schema)

val test = pos.withColumn("test", myUDF(col("description")))
    test.printSchema()
val a =test.withColumn("mode", col("test").getItem("_1"))
    .withColumn("store", col("test").getItem("_2"))
    .withColumn("type", col("test").getItem("_3"))
    .drop(col("test"))

a.printSchema()
a.show(5, false)
```

I get the below error when I execute

> 18/10/06 21:38:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0
>   (TID 5) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user
>   defined function($anonfun$myFunc1$1$1: (string) =>
>   struct(mode:string,store:string,type:string))     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   -4    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)     at com.hasif.bank.track.trasaction.TransactionParser$$anonfun$myFunc1$1$1.apply(TransactionParser.scala:26)
>     at
>   com.hasif.bank.track.trasaction.TransactionParser$$anonfun$myFunc1$1$1.apply(TransactionParser.scala:22)
>     ... 16 more

Any pointers on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

```
scala> val df = Seq("ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX STORE NAME ABC TYPE1").toDF("desc")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [desc: string]

scala> df.withColumn("mode",split('desc," ")(0)).withColumn("type",split('desc," ")(5)).withColumn("store",concat(split('desc," ")(2), lit(" "), split('desc," ")(3))).show(false)
+-------------------------------------+----+-----+----------+
|desc                                 |mode|type |store     |
+-------------------------------------+----+-----+----------+
|ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX STORE NAME ABC TYPE1|ABC |TYPE1|STORE NAME|
+-------------------------------------+----+-----+----------+


scala>
```

**Update1:**

```
scala> def splitStore(x:String):String=
     | return x.split(" ").drop(2).init.init.mkString(" ")
splitStore: (x: String)String

scala> val mysplitstore = udf(splitStore(_:String):String)
mysplitstore: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> val df2 = Seq("ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX STORE NAME XYZ ABC TYPE1").toDF("desc")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [desc: string]

scala> val df3 = df2.withColumn("length",split('desc," "))
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [desc: string, length: array<string>]

scala> val df4 = df3.withColumn("mode",split('desc," ")(size('length)-2)).withColumn("type",split('desc," ")(size('length)-1)).withColumn("store",mysplitstore('desc))
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [desc: string, length: array<string> ... 3 more fields]

scala> df4.drop('length).show(false)
+-----------------------------------------+----+-----+--------------+
|desc                                     |mode|type |store         |
+-----------------------------------------+----+-----+--------------+
|ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX STORE NAME XYZ ABC TYPE1|ABC |TYPE1|STORE NAME XYZ|
+-----------------------------------------+----+-----+--------------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The challenge here is that the value of store could be more than 2 words

Comment: can I assume that mode and type will be last 2 columns, the first 2 words will be the description and whatever goes in the middle will be store name?

Comment: I missed the boundary case.. updated again. please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181417/discussion-between-hasif-and-stack0114106).