# Efficient way to use If-Else in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am having a `DataFrame` below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, length, lit, concat
values = [(1,'USA','12424','AB+'),(2,'Japan','63252','B-'),(3,'Ireland','23655',None),(4,'France','57366','O+'),
          (5,'Ireland','82351','A-'),(6,'USA','35854','B+'),(7,'Ireland','5835','AB-'),(8,'USA','95255','B+')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['id','country','postcode','bloodgroup'])
df.show()
+---+-------+--------+----------+
| id|country|postcode|bloodgroup|
+---+-------+--------+----------+
|  1|    USA|   12424|       AB+|
|  2|  Japan|   63252|        B-|
|  3|Ireland|   23655|      null|
|  4| France|   57366|        O+|
|  5|Ireland|   82351|        A-|
|  6|    USA|   35854|        B+|
|  7|Ireland|    5835|       AB-|
|  8|    USA|   95255|        B+|
+---+-------+--------+----------+
```

I need to make changes in columns `postcode` & `bloodgroup` according to the following conditions, as summarised in this rough `python pseudocode` -

```
# Efficient (pseudocode 1)
if country == 'Ireland':
    if length(postcode) == 4:
        postcode = '0'+postcode   # Append 0 to postcode incase it's 4 digit.
    if bloodgroup == null: 
        bloodgroup = 'Unknown'
```

As you can see in the pseudocode above, the check `country == 'Ireland'` was done **only once** as it was a common clause in the two conditions. Doing the other way by coupling this clause with the other two conditions using `and` would have been inefficient -

```
# Inefficient (pseudocode 2)
if country == 'Ireland' and length(postcode) == 4:
        postcode = '0'+postcode   
if country == 'Ireland' and bloodgroup == null: 
        bloodgroup = 'Unknown'
```

I am using `PySpark` and the only way I know how to do this is as follows -

```
df = df.withColumn('postcode',when((col('country') == 'Ireland') & (length(col('postcode')) == 4),concat(lit('0'),col('postcode'))).otherwise(col('postcode')))
df = df.withColumn('bloodgroup',when((col('country') == 'Ireland') & col('bloodgroup').isNull(),'Unknown').otherwise(col('bloodgroup')))
df.show()
+---+-------+--------+----------+
| id|country|postcode|bloodgroup|
+---+-------+--------+----------+
|  1|    USA|   12424|       AB+|
|  2|  Japan|   63252|        B-|
|  3|Ireland|   23655|   Unknown|
|  4| France|   57366|        O+|
|  5|Ireland|   82351|        A-|
|  6|    USA|   35854|        B+|
|  7|Ireland|   05835|       AB-|
|  8|    USA|   95255|        B+|
+---+-------+--------+----------+
```

But, this corresponds to the inefficient pseudocode I wrote above, because we are checking `country == 'Ireland'` two times. I have checked the `executionPlan` using `df.explain()` and it does not do any automatic optimization, which I thought catalyst might to.

How can we write a `PySpark` code corresponding to pseudocode 1, where we do the check of country once and then test the 2 conditions?

Comment: I can think of a way to do this similar to the "efficient" approach you showed, but it would return a `StructType` column. Otherwise, chained `withColumn` statements are probably the most efficient you're going to get since there's no easy way to [get multiple columns in a single call to withColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196207/derive-multiple-columns-from-a-single-column-in-a-spark-dataframe).

Comment: Many thanks Pault for your comments. Always appreciated. Thanks a lot referring me to this link. I will investigate it further.