# How to query JSON data column using Spark DataFrames?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra table that for simplicity looks something like:

```
key: text
jsonData: text
blobData: blob
```

I can create a basic data frame for this using spark and the spark-cassandra-connector using:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "mytable", "keyspace" -> "ks1"))
  .load()
```

I'm struggling though to expand the JSON data into its underlying structure.  I ultimately want to be able to filter based on the attributes within the json string and return the blob data.  Something like jsonData.foo = "bar" and return blobData.  Is this currently possible?

Comment: Is `key` an unique identifier?

Comment: yes, key is the primary key of the table

Comment: See this; excellent example of how to flatten: https://bigdataprogrammers.com/read-nested-json-in-spark-dataframe/

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**

If needed, schema can be determined using [`schema_of_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#schema_of_json(json:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function (please note that this assumes that an arbitrary row is a valid representative of the schema).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, schema_of_json, from_json}
import collection.JavaConverters._

val schema = schema_of_json(lit(df.select($"jsonData").as[String].first))
df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json($"jsonData", schema, Map[String, String]().asJava))
```

**Spark >= 2.1**

You can use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:String,options:java.util.Map%5BString,String%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("k", StringType, true), StructField("v", DoubleType, true)
))

df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json($"jsonData", schema))
```

**Spark >= 1.6**

You can use `get_json_object` which takes a column and a path:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.get_json_object

val exprs = Seq("k", "v").map(
  c => get_json_object($"jsonData", s"$$.$c").alias(c))

df.select($"*" +: exprs: _*)
```

and extracts fields to individual strings which can be further casted to expected types.

The `path` argument is expressed using dot syntax, with leading `$.` denoting document root (since the code above uses string interpolation `$` has to be escaped, hence `$$.`).

**Spark <= 1.5**:

> Is this currently possible?

As far as I know it is not directly possible. You can try something similar to this:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("1", """{"k": "foo", "v": 1.0}""", "some_other_field_1"),
  ("2", """{"k": "bar", "v": 3.0}""", "some_other_field_2")
)).toDF("key", "jsonData", "blobData")
```

I assume that `blob` field cannot be represented in JSON. Otherwise you cab omit splitting and joining:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val blobs = df.drop("jsonData").withColumnRenamed("key", "bkey")
val jsons = sqlContext.read.json(df.drop("blobData").map{
  case Row(key: String, json: String) =>
    s"""{"key": "$key", "jsonData": $json}"""
}) 

val parsed = jsons.join(blobs, $"key" === $"bkey").drop("bkey")
parsed.printSchema

// root
//  |-- jsonData: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- k: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- v: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- key: long (nullable = true)
//  |-- blobData: string (nullable = true)
```

An alternative (cheaper, although more complex) approach is to use an UDF to parse JSON and output a `struct` or `map` column. For example something like this:

```
import net.liftweb.json.parse

case class KV(k: String, v: Int)

val parseJson = udf((s: String) => {
  implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
  parse(s).extract[KV]
})

val parsed = df.withColumn("parsedJSON", parseJson($"jsonData"))
parsed.show

// +---+--------------------+------------------+----------+
// |key|            jsonData|          blobData|parsedJSON|
// +---+--------------------+------------------+----------+
// |  1|{"k": "foo", "v":...|some_other_field_1|   [foo,1]|
// |  2|{"k": "bar", "v":...|some_other_field_2|   [bar,3]|
// +---+--------------------+------------------+----------+

parsed.printSchema

// root
//  |-- key: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- jsonData: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- blobData: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- parsedJSON: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- k: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- v: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: giving `StructType`  not working in spark 2.2.0 for `to_json`  `   List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>(2);
       fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("a", DataTypes.StringType, false));
    
       StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

     
     g4.withColumn("dd", 
       
       
       functions.to_json(functions.col("a"),schema)
       ).show();  `

Comment: If you're looking for a more comprehensive approach that accounts for schema variability in your JSON data, you should probably use `spark.read.json()`. I have the details plus a full example in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60531370/877069).

Answer (score 42):

[zero323's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34069986/877069) is thorough but misses one approach that is available in Spark 2.1+ and is simpler and more robust than using `schema_of_json()`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json

val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select("jsonData").as[String]).schema
df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json($"jsonData", json_schema))
```

Here's the Python equivalent:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select("jsonData").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).schema
df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json("jsonData", json_schema))
```

The problem with `schema_of_json()`, as zero323 points out, is that it inspects a single string and derives a schema from that. If you have JSON data with varied schemas, then the schema you get back from `schema_of_json()` will not reflect what you would get if you were to merge the schemas of all the JSON data in your DataFrame. Parsing that data with `from_json()` will then yield a lot of `null` or empty values where the schema returned by `schema_of_json()` doesn't match the data.

By using Spark's ability to derive a comprehensive JSON schema from an RDD of JSON strings, we can guarantee that all the JSON data can be parsed.

## Example: `schema_of_json()` vs. `spark.read.json()`

Here's an example (in Python, the code is very similar for Scala) to illustrate the difference between deriving the schema from a single element with `schema_of_json()` and deriving it from all the data using `spark.read.json()`.

```python
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...     [
...         (1, '{"a": true}'),
...         (2, '{"a": "hello"}'),
...         (3, '{"b": 22}'),
...     ],
...     schema=['id', 'jsonData'],
... )
```

`a` has a boolean value in one row and a string value in another. The merged schema for `a` would set its type to string. `b` would be an integer.

Let's see how the different approaches compare. First, the `schema_of_json()` approach:

```python
>>> json_schema = schema_of_json(df.select("jsonData").take(1)[0][0])
>>> parsed_json_df = df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json("jsonData", json_schema))
>>> parsed_json_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- jsonData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: boolean (nullable = true)

>>> parsed_json_df.show()
+---+--------+
| id|jsonData|
+---+--------+
|  1|  [true]|
|  2|    null|
|  3|      []|
+---+--------+
```

As you can see, the JSON schema we derived was very limited. `"a": "hello"` couldn't be parsed as a boolean and returned `null`, and `"b": 22` was just dropped because it wasn't in our schema.

Now with `spark.read.json()`:

```python
>>> json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select("jsonData").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).schema
>>> parsed_json_df = df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json("jsonData", json_schema))
>>> parsed_json_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- jsonData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)

>>> parsed_json_df.show()
+---+--------+
| id|jsonData|
+---+--------+
|  1| [true,]|
|  2|[hello,]|
|  3|  [, 22]|
+---+--------+
```

Here we have all our data preserved, and with a comprehensive schema that accounts for all the data. `"a": true` was cast as a string to match the schema of `"a": "hello"`.

The main downside of using `spark.read.json()` is that Spark will scan through all your data to derive the schema. Depending on how much data you have, that overhead could be significant. If you *know* that all your JSON data has a consistent schema, it's fine to go ahead and just use `schema_of_json()` against a single element. If you have schema variability but don't want to scan through all your data, you can set `samplingRatio` to something less than `1.0` in your call to `spark.read.json()` to look at a subset of the data.

Here are the docs for `spark.read.json()`: [Scala API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) / [Python API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is such an elegant solution and should be the accepted solution to this question.

Comment: This is such a comprehensive solution! Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The `from_json` function is exactly what you're looking for. Your code will look something like:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "mytable", "keyspace" -> "ks1"))
  .load()

//You can define whatever struct type that your json states
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("key", StringType, true), 
  StructField("value", DoubleType, true)
))

df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json(col("jsonData"), schema))
```

Answer (score 1):

underlying JSON String is

```
"{ \"column_name1\":\"value1\",\"column_name2\":\"value2\",\"column_name3\":\"value3\",\"column_name5\":\"value5\"}";
```

Below is the script to filter the JSON and load the required data in to Cassandra.

```
  sqlContext.read.json(rdd).select("column_name1 or fields name in Json", "column_name2","column_name2")
            .write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(Map("table" -> "Table_name", "keyspace" -> "Key_Space_name"))
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following

(available since 2.2.0, and i am assuming that your json string column is at column index 0)

```
def parse(df: DataFrame, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val stringDf = df.map((value: Row) => value.getString(0), Encoders.STRING)
    spark.read.json(stringDf)
}
```

It will automatically infer the schema in your JSON. Documented here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html