# Spark: Generating JSON schema for a JSON string

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Im using **Spark 2.4.3 and Scala 2.11**

Below is my current JSON string in a DataFrame column.
Im trying to store the schema of this `JSON string` in another column using `schema_of_json` function.
But its throwing below the error. How could I resolve this?

```
{
  "company": {
    "companyId": "123",
    "companyName": "ABC"
  },
  "customer": {
    "customerDetails": {
      "customerId": "CUST-100",
      "customerName": "CUST-AAA",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "phone": {
        "phoneDetails": {
          "home": {
            "phoneno": "666-777-9999"
          },
          "mobile": {
            "phoneno": "333-444-5555"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "address": {
      "loc": "NORTH",
      "adressDetails": [
        {
          "street": "BBB",
          "city": "YYYYY",
          "province": "AB",
          "country": "US"
        },
        {
          "street": "UUU",
          "city": "GGGGG",
          "province": "NB",
          "country": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Code:

```
val df = spark.read.textFile("./src/main/resources/json/company.txt")
df.printSchema()
df.show()

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"company":{"companyId":"123","companyName":"ABC"},"customer":{"customerDetails":{"customerId":"CUST-100","customerName":"CUST-AAA","status":"ACTIVE","phone":{"phoneDetails":{"home":{"phoneno":"666-777-9999"},"mobile":{"phoneno":"333-444-5555"}}}},"address":{"loc":"NORTH","adressDetails":[{"street":"BBB","city":"YYYYY","province":"AB","country":"US"},{"street":"UUU","city":"GGGGG","province":"NB","country":"US"}]}}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


df.withColumn("jsonSchema",schema_of_json(col("value")))
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'schemaofjson(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: The input json should be a string literal and not null; however, got `value`.;;
'Project [value#0, schemaofjson(value#0) AS jsonSchema#10]
+- Project [value#0]
   +- Relation[value#0] text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workaround solution that I found was to pass the column `value` as below to the `schema_of_json` function.

```
df.withColumn("jsonSchema",schema_of_json(df.select(col("value")).first.getString(0)))
```

Courtesy:

[Implicit schema discovery on a JSON-formatted Spark DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688278/implicit-schema-discovery-on-a-json-formatted-spark-dataframe-column)

Comment: For pyspark it would be
```df.withColumn("jsonSchema",schema_of_json(df.select(col("value")).first()[0]))```

Answer (score 1):

Since [SPARK-24709](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22775) was introduced `schema_of_json` accepts just literal strings. You can extract schema of `String` in `DDL` format by calling

```
spark.read
  .json(df.select("value").as[String])
  .schema
  .toDDL
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case, NOT every row has the same json string with same schema. How do I handle that with this?

Answer (score 0):

If one is looking for a pyspark answer :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import json
    
  def process(json_content):
      if json_content is None : 
        return []
      try:
        # Parse the content of the json, extract the keys only
        keys = json.loads(json_content).keys()
        return list(keys)
      except Exception as e:
        return [e]
    
    udf_function = F.udf(process_file, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
    my_df = my_df.withColumn("schema", udf_function(F.col("json_raw"))
```