# Spark: Unit Test - I have one function that unions 3 input datasets. Should I do Unit test on them?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a code part of which is as below

```
Object Cal{
def mergedatasets(df: Dataset[Row], df1: Dataset[Row],df2: Dataset[Row]):Dataset[Row]={
 df.union(df1).union(df2)
//other logic

}

}
object readDataframes{
def readFirstDF(spark:SparkSession):Dataset[Row]={
 spark.read.json(somefile)
}
def readSecondDF(spark:SparkSession):Dataset[Row]={
 spark.read.json(somefile)
}
def readThirdDF(spark:SparkSession):Dataset[Row]={
 spark.read.json(somefile)
}
}
```

In the above code I am reading 3 files and then merging them into one which I use further for processing.
Based on the above scenario my questions are as follows:

1. Does it make sense to Unit test the function mergdatasets? If yes, What are the basic/minimal things to test for?How to check for corner cases, if any?
2. Does it make sense to Unit test readDataframes?If yes what to test for ?Would it be to check if inferred schema is as expected? and anything else?

I would like to extend the above questions for the following functions too

```
def timeIntervalAgg(df: Dataset[Row]): Dataset[Row] = {

    val timeInterval = df
      .groupBy("id","page_number")
      .agg(sum("timeInterval").alias("timeInterval"))
    timeIntervalAgg

  }

  def timeInterval(df: Dataset[Row]): Dataset[Row] ={

    val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date_time")
    val timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    val endTime = lead(col("date_time"),1).over(windowSpec)
    val startTime = col("date_time")
    val timeDiff = (unix_timestamp(endTime, timeFmt)
      - unix_timestamp(startTime, timeFmt))
    val timeInterval = df
      .withColumn("timeInterval", lit(when(col("event") === "this_event",lit(null)
        .cast("long"))
        .otherwise(timeDiff)))
      .where("""event != "this_event" """)
    timeInterval

  }

  def addOddpages(df: Dataset[Row]) :Dataset[Row] = {

    val odd = df
      .where("""view_mode = "twin" """)
      .withColumn("page_odd", col("page") + 1)
      .drop("page")
      .select(col("id"), col("date_time")
        .cast("timestamp"),col("page_odd")
        .alias("page"), col("page_view_mode"),
        col("event"),col("timeInterval"))
    val timeIntervalWithoddPage = df.union(odd)
    timeIntervalWithoddPage

  }
```

- Please suggest if it is needed to refactor the code in a better way
  to enable better testing.
- My goal is to understand what to test for? what to look out while
  writing test for code like above? All this questions are for Spark
  code Unit testing not other language code testing.
- How to unit test without redundantly testing spark which is already
  tested?
- Is it needed to test every function like this(since the logic/code is not very complicated) or is best to test the
  function that combines the above functions in proper order.By doing
  so can it be called unit testing?
- Please feel free to share some sample Unit tests that you may write
  for above code.

Comment: I would not unit-test these methods, `union` and `spark.read` should be unit-tested by `spark` itself. What you could test is the behavior if arguments are null, i.e. you could test if an appropriate exception is thrown

Comment: the `readDataframes` method do not make much sense, why do they take a `Dataframe` as an input, I would expect they take a file path/name (string)?

Comment: Yes, let me correct that for read statements

Answer (score 0):

Read JSON files:  If you just read JSON files, you don't need to test this. 
In addition, it might be better to read the files with explicit schema in `schema()` to avoid some issues with inferred schema. Also, you do not need 3 identical methods  for reading the files.

Union Datasets: Since Spark 2.3.0 there is `unionByName()` function.
That function resolves columns by name (not by position). You can consider the functions to avoid issues with union when your DataFrames have different order of columns. Of course, this function doesn't need to be tested. It's hard to say about the `//other logic` code inside the `mergedatasets()` method.

For unit testing, you can use ScalaTest or other tools.

- Create SparkSession with `master("local")`;
- Create a DataFrame with the expected data;
- Create an input DataFrame for each method you want to test.;
- Compare expected and actual DataFrames;

The following project might be useful. You can find there how to compare two DataFrames. Also, there are several examples in the README: https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests