# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve :While reading data from nested json

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

can anyone please guide me how should i access amt1,amt2,total from this json schema. after loading json file when i am trying to select data   using

```
     df.select($"b2b.bill.amt1").
```

I am getting below error message.

```
     org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b2b`.`bill`['amt1']' due to data type 
     mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''amt1'' is of string type.;;

    Json Schema:

    |-- b2b: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- transid: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- bill: array (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |    |    |-- amt1: double (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |    |-- amt2: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |    |-- total: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Tried locally. Same issue. Interesting question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SPARK: How to parse a Array of JSON object using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970480/spark-how-to-parse-a-array-of-json-object-using-spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is `amt1` is an property of an object which is inside of two array types i.e `b2b` and `bill`. you need to explode twice to access `amt1` field.

Check below code.

```
scala> adf.printSchema
root
 |-- b2b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- bill: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- amt1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- amt2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- total: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- transid: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> adf.select(explode($"b2b.bill").as("bill")).withColumn("bill",explode($"bill")).select("bill.*").show(false)
+----+----+-----+
|amt1|amt2|total|
+----+----+-----+
|10.0|20  |ttl  |
+----+----+-----+
```

Another way .. but its only give first value from the array.

```
scala> adf.select(explode($"b2b.bill"(0)("amt1")).as("amt1")).show(false)
+----+
|amt1|
+----+
|10.0|
+----+
```

```
scala> adf.selectExpr("explode(b2b.bill[0].amt1) as amt1").show(false)
+----+
|amt1|
+----+
|10.0|
+----+
```