# Use Spark to parse a JSON array column and carry ID column along as well

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with two columns -- one called `json`, a string containing a JSON *array*, and the other an `Int` called `id`. If I select just the `json` column and convert the resulting `DataFrame` to a `Dataset`, then parse the json using `Reader.json()`, the JSON array in the resulting `DataFrame` will be exploded out into multiple rows. Now there's no way I can see to correlate `id` back to the correct exploded rows. In Java this looks something like:

```
Dataset<Row> df = reader.table("myTable"); // DataFrame containing json and id
df = df.selectExpr("json");                // DataFrame containing just json
Dataset<String> ds = df.toJavaRDD()        // Dataset<String> containing just json
    .map((Function<Row, String>) row -> (String) row.get(0)).rdd(), STRING());
df = reader.schema(jsonDdl).json(ds);      // exploded DataFrame, one row per array element
```

...now what? I have no way to correlate `id` back to the rows coming from the JSON parse operation. How can I do this differently such that the relationship between `id` and the parsed JSON columns is preserved?

Comment: select `df=df.selectExpr("json","id")` then in `jsonDdl` include id column too!

Comment: @Shu thanks, but won't that just cause Spark to look for the `id` column inside the JSON string?

Comment: @Shu the other problem with that is `DataFrameReader.json()` will accept a `Dataset<String>` in Java, or an `RDD<String>` (deprecated) but not a `DataFrame` (a.k.a. `Dataset<Row>`), so there's no way to sneak an extra column in there alongside the JSON string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query JSON data column using Spark DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069282/how-to-query-json-data-column-using-spark-dataframes)

Comment: Can you supply a data representation. Trying to understand why `DataFrameReader.json()` would cause an explosion _and_ if we can do a pre-processing step to introduce `id` in json itself.

Comment: @D3V any JSON that is an array at the outer level, not an object, will result in row explosion to expand that outer array.