# How do I flattern a pySpark dataframe by one array column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
+------+--------+--------------+--------------------+
|   dbn|    boro|total_students|                sBus|
+------+--------+--------------+--------------------+
|17K548|Brooklyn|           399|[B41, B43, B44-SB...|
|09X543|   Bronx|           378|[Bx13, Bx15, Bx17...|
|09X327|   Bronx|           543|[Bx1, Bx11, Bx13,...|
+------+--------+--------------+--------------------+
```

How do I flattern it so that each row is copied for each for each element in sBus, and sBus will be a normal string column?

So that result would be like this:

```
+------+--------+--------------+--------------------+
|   dbn|    boro|total_students|                sBus|
+------+--------+--------------+--------------------+
|17K548|Brooklyn|           399| B41                |
|17K548|Brooklyn|           399| B43                |
|17K548|Brooklyn|           399| B44-SB             |
+------+--------+--------------+--------------------+
```

and so on...

Comment: Could you provide expected output? Do you expect Cartesian product between `sBus` and `sSw` as a result?

Comment: thanks! added the expected result. For the sake of simplicity, removed sSw column

Comment: Well, you can use `explode` (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/36484385/1560062) but it is not that simple if you have multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this without turning it into an RDD.

```py
# convert df to rdd
rdd = df.rdd

def extract(row, key):
    """Takes dictionary and key, returns tuple of (dict w/o key, dict[key])."""
    _dict = row.asDict()
    _list = _dict[key]
    del _dict[key]
    return (_dict, _list)


def add_to_dict(_dict, key, value):
    _dict[key] = value
    return _dict


# preserve rest of values in key, put list to flatten in value
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: extract(x, 'sBus'))
# make a row for each item in value
rdd = rdd.flatMapValues(lambda x: x)
# add flattened value back into dictionary
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: add_to_dict(x[0], 'sBus', x[1]))
# convert back to dataframe
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)

df.show()
```

The tricky part is keeping the other columns together with the newly flattened values. I do this by mapping each row to a tuple of `(dict of other columns, list to flatten)` and then calling [`flatMapValues`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMapValues). This will split each element of the value list into a separate row, but keep the keys attached, i.e.

```
(key, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

becomes

```
(key, 'A')
(key, 'B')
(key, 'C')
```

Then, I move the flattened value back into the dictionary of other columns, and reconvert it back to a DataFrame.