# How do I flattern a pySpark dataframe ?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
id |            Operation                 |        Value 
----------------------------------------------------------- 
1  | [Date_Min, Date_Max, Device]         | [148590, 148590, iphone]     
2  | [Date_Min, Date_Max, Review]         | [148590, 148590, Good]     
3  | [Date_Min, Date_Max, Review, Device] | [148590, 148590, Bad,samsung]
```

The resul that i expect:

```
id | Operation |  Value |
-------------------------- 
1  | Date_Min  | 148590 |
1  | Date_Max  | 148590 |
1  | Device    | iphone |
2  | Date_Min  | 148590 |
2  | Date_Max  | 148590 |
2  | Review    | Good   |
3  | Date_Min  | 148590 |
3  | Date_Max  | 148590 |
3  | Review    | Bad    |
3  | Review    | samsung|
```

I'm using Spark 2.1.0 with pyspark. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758854/how-do-i-flattern-a-pyspark-dataframe-by-one-array-column)  but it worked only for one column.

Thanks

Comment: I still cannot figure out the good way to do this particular task. I tried to explode columns separately `df1 = df.select('id', explode(col("Operation")))`, 
`df2 = df.select('id', explode(col("Value")))`. However, there is no good solution on how to horizontally stack two dataframe together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example dataframe from above. I use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027315/pyspark-split-multiple-array-columns-into-rows) in order to solve your question.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
     [[1, ['Date_Min', 'Date_Max', 'Device'], ['148590', '148590', 'iphone']], 
      [2, ['Date_Min', 'Date_Max', 'Review'], ['148590', '148590', 'Good']],     
      [3, ['Date_Min', 'Date_Max', 'Review', 'Device'], ['148590', '148590', 'Bad', 'samsung']]], 
     schema=['id', 'l1', 'l2'])
```

Here, you can define `udf` to zip two list together for each row first.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, explode

zip_list = udf(
  lambda x, y: list(zip(x, y)),
  ArrayType(StructType([
      StructField("first", StringType()),
      StructField("second", StringType())
  ]))
)
```

Finally, you can zip two columns together then explode that column.

```
df_out = df.withColumn("tmp", zip_list('l1', 'l2')).\
    withColumn("tmp", explode("tmp")).\
    select('id', col('tmp.first').alias('Operation'), col('tmp.second').alias('Value'))
df_out.show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+---------+-------+
| id|Operation|  Value|
+---+---------+-------+
|  1| Date_Min| 148590|
|  1| Date_Max| 148590|
|  1|   Device| iphone|
|  2| Date_Min| 148590|
|  2| Date_Max| 148590|
|  2|   Review|   Good|
|  3| Date_Min| 148590|
|  3| Date_Max| 148590|
|  3|   Review|    Bad|
|  3|   Device|samsung|
+---+---------+-------+
```

Comment: No problem @Omar14!

Comment: Finally, i still have a problem with the function zip_list. When i work with Zeppelin notebook it works but when i tried to automate the job and the script with spark-submit, the job failed with this error:
`zip argument #1 must support iteration`

Answer (score -1):

If using DataFrame then try this:-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

your_df.select("id", F.explode("Operation"), F.explode("Value")).show()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I explode 2 columns at the same time.