# Split a column in multiple columns with given column name and value in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df like this

```
+-----+-------+------------+---+---+----+------+--------------------+
|CHROM|    POS|          ID|REF|ALT|QUAL|FILTER|                INFO|
+-----+-------+------------+---+---+----+------+--------------------+
|    1|1014143| rs786201005|  C|  T|   .|     .|RS=786201005;RSPO...|
|    1|1014228|      rs1921|  G|A,C|   .|     .|RS=1921;RSPOS=101...|
|    1|1014316| rs672601345|  C| CG|   .|     .|RS=672601345;RSPO...|
|    1|1014359| rs672601312|  G|  T|   .|     .|RS=672601312;RSPO...|
|    1|1020183| rs539283387|  G|  C|   .|     .|RS=539283387;RSPO...|
|    1|1020216| rs764659938|  C|  G|   .|     .|RS=764659938;RSPO...|
|    1|1020217| rs115173026|  G|  T|   .|     .|RS=115173026;RSPO...|
|    1|1020221|rs1057523287|  C|  T|   .|     .|RS=1057523287;RSP...|
|    1|1020239| rs201073369|  G|A,C|   .|     .|RS=201073369;RSPO...|
|    1|1022188| rs115704555|  A|  G|   .|     .|RS=115704555;RSPO...|
+-----+-------+------------+---+---+----+------+--------------------+
```

My info column has multiple value separated by ';' which are in the form of 'column_name=value'. I want my df info columns separated in multiple columns on the basis of respective value like this

```
Pre_Col| Info               |      RS    | RSPOS |dbSNPBuildID| SSR |...|
-------+--------------------+------------+-------+------------+-----+---+
...    |RS=786201005;RSPO...|  786201005 |1012143|  144       |  0  |...|
...    |RS=115173026;RSPO...|  115173026 |9043523|  123       |  2  |...|
```

info column can has multiple variable values. It is possible that RS value can not be in other rows, same case can be possible with other values. In that case i want RS value as 'null'. I'm driving this df through a map.

After one suggestion i have edited my code and get below result

```
+-----+-------+------------+---+---+----+------+--------------------+-----+
|CHROM|    POS|          ID|REF|ALT|QUAL|FILTER|                INFO|  kvs|
+-----+-------+------------+---+---+----+------+--------------------+-----+
|    1|1014143| rs786201005|  C|  T|   .|     .|RS=786201005;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1014228|      rs1921|  G|A,C|   .|     .|RS=1921;RSPOS=101...|Map()|
|    1|1014316| rs672601345|  C| CG|   .|     .|RS=672601345;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1014359| rs672601312|  G|  T|   .|     .|RS=672601312;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1020183| rs539283387|  G|  C|   .|     .|RS=539283387;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1020216| rs764659938|  C|  G|   .|     .|RS=764659938;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1020217| rs115173026|  G|  T|   .|     .|RS=115173026;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1020221|rs1057523287|  C|  T|   .|     .|RS=1057523287;RSP...|Map()|
|    1|1020239| rs201073369|  G|A,C|   .|     .|RS=201073369;RSPO...|Map()|
|    1|1022188| rs115704555|  A|  G|   .|     .|RS=115704555;RSPO...|Map()|
+-----+-------+------------+---+---+----+------+--------------------+-----+
```

and my schema is

```
root
|-- CHROM: string (nullable = true)
|-- POS: string (nullable = true)
|-- ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- REF: string (nullable = true)
|-- ALT: string (nullable = true)
|-- QUAL: string (nullable = true)
|-- FILTER: string (nullable = true)
|-- INFO: string (nullable = true)
|-- kvs: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Can i split these map values further into columns?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your code in the current state so we can help you to improve it and get the desired solution.

Comment: Will you be having `RS=;RSPO..` when RS is null? Are `RS, RSPOS,dbSNPBuildID, SSR` are the only columns that will exist inside `Info` ?

Comment: @philantrovert, no there can be many columns inside info can be 27 or many more

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the answer from [PySpark converting a column of type 'map' to multiple columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36869134/8371915):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, explode

@udf("map<string,string>")
def to_map(s):
    if s:
        kvs = [x.split("=") for x in s.split(";")]
        return {kv[0]: kv[1] for kv in kvs if len(kvs) == 2}

with_map = df.withColumn("kvs", to_map("INFO"))

keys = (with_map
  .select(explode("kvs"))
  .select("key")
  .distinct()
  .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
  .collect())

with_map.select(*["*"] + [col("kvs").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in keys])
```

For older versions:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def to_map_(s):
    if s:
        kvs = [x.split("=") for x in s.split(";")]
        return {kv[0]: kv[1] for kv in kvs if len(kvs) == 2}

to_map = udf(to_map_, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
```