# Expand column with array of structs into new columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame with a single column which is an array of structs

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- dataCells: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Some sample data might look like this:

```
df.first()
Row(dataCells=[Row(label="firstName", value="John"), Row(label="lastName", value="Doe"), Row(label="Date", value="1/29/2018")])
```

I'm trying to figure out how to reformat this DataFrame by turning each struct into a named column.  I want to have a DataFrame like this:

```
------------------------------------
| firstName | lastName | Date      |
------------------------------------
| John      | Doe      | 1/29/2018 |
| ....      | ...      | ...       |
```

I've tried everything I can think of but haven't figured this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just explode and select `*`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, first, col, monotonically_increasing_id

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(dataCells=[Row(label="firstName", value="John"), Row(label="lastName", value="Doe"), Row(label="Date", value="1/29/2018")])
])

long = (df
   .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
   .select("id", explode("dataCells").alias("col"))
   .select("id", "col.*"))
```

and `pivot`:

```py
long.groupBy("id").pivot("label").agg(first("value")).show()
# +-----------+---------+---------+--------+                                      
# |         id|     Date|firstName|lastName|
# +-----------+---------+---------+--------+
# |25769803776|1/29/2018|     John|     Doe|
# +-----------+---------+---------+--------+
```

You can also:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("map<string,string>")
def as_map(x):
    return dict(x)

cols = [col("dataCells")[c].alias(c) for c in ["Date", "firstName", "lastName"]]
df.select(as_map("dataCells").alias("dataCells")).select(cols).show()

# +---------+---------+--------+
# |     Date|firstName|lastName|
# +---------+---------+--------+
# |1/29/2018|     John|     Doe|
# +---------+---------+--------+
```

References:

- [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494/8371915)
- [PySpark converting a column of type 'map' to multiple columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36869134/8371915)

Comment: Great answer.  I ran into the following error "The pivot column label has more than 10000 distinct values", which gave me some concerns about the performance of this approach in the long run.

Comment: It is a concern. Spark doesn't handle wide data well. In that case I'd recommend the second solution - both `explode` and `pivot` are on the expensive side.

Comment: This works perfectly but with a slight caveat, if you have a record which is an empty array and you explode it, the row would be eliminated altogether, which might be a problem if you want to preserve empties. I suggest, using explode_outer instead and after pivoting, the result would have a null column, which you can subsequently drop.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach I tried without UDF,

```
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+
|           dataCells|
+--------------------+
|[[firstName,John]...|
+--------------------+

>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F

## size of array with maximum length in column 
>>> arr_len = df.select(F.max(F.size('dataCells')).alias('len')).first().len

## get values from struct 
>>> df1 = df.select([df.dataCells[i].value for i in range(arr_len)])
>>> df1.show()
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|dataCells[0].value|dataCells[1].value|dataCells[2].value|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              John|               Doe|         1/29/2018|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+

>>> oldcols = df1.columns

## get the labels from struct
>>> cols = df.select([df.dataCells[i].label.alias('col_%s'%i) for i in range(arr_len)]).dropna().first()
>>> cols
Row(dataCells[0].label=u'firstName', dataCells[1].label=u'lastName', dataCells[2].label=u'Date')
>>> newcols = [cols[i] for i in range(arr_len)]
>>> newcols
[u'firstName', u'lastName', u'Date']

## use the labels to rename the columns
>>> df2 = reduce(lambda data, idx: data.withColumnRenamed(oldcols[idx], newcols[idx]), range(len(oldcols)), df1)
>>> df2.show()
+---------+--------+---------+
|firstName|lastName|     Date|
+---------+--------+---------+
|     John|     Doe|1/29/2018|
+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Note that this will work only if all rows contain the same set of tuples in the same order. That's a risky assumption.