# PySpark Map to Columns, rename key columns

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, key, multiple-columns

I am converting the Map column to multiple columns dynamically based on the values in the column. I am using the following code (taken mostly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869134/pyspark-converting-a-column-of-type-map-to-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe#63026111)), and it works perfectly fine.

However, I would like to rename the column names that are programmatically generated.

Input df:

```
| map_col                                                                        |
|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| {"customer_id":"c5","email":"abc@yahoo.com","mobile_number":"1234567890"}      |
| null                                                                           |
| {"customer_id":"c3","mobile_number":"2345678901","email":"xyz@gmail.com"}      |
| {"email":"pqr@hotmail.com","customer_id":"c8","mobile_number":"3456789012"}    |
| {"email":"mnk@GMAIL.COM"}                                                      |
```

Code to convert Map to Columns

```py
keys_df = df.select(F.explode(F.map_keys(F.col("map_col")))).distinct()`
keys = list(map(lambda row: row[0], keys_df.collect()))
key_cols = list(map(lambda f: F.col("map_col").getItem(f).alias(str(f)), keys))
final_cols = [F.col("*")] + key_cols
df = df.select(final_cols)
```

Output df:

```
| customer_id | mobile_number | email           |
|:----------- |:--------------| :---------------|
| c5          | 1234567890    | abc@yahoo.com   |
| null        | null          | null            |
| c3          | 2345678901    | xyz@gmail.com   |
| c8          | 3456789012    | pqr@hotmail.com |
| null        | null          | mnk@GMAIL.COM   |
```

I already have the fields customer_id, mobile_number and email in the main dataframe, of which map_col is one of the columns. I get error when I try to generate the output because same column names are already in the dataset. Therefore, **I need to rename these column names to customer_id_2, mobile_number_2, and email_2 before it is generated in the dataset**. map_col column may have more keys and values than shown.

Desired output:

```
| customer_id_2 | mobile_number_2  | email_2         |
|:------------- |:-----------------| :---------------|
| c5            | 1234567890       | abc@yahoo.com   |
| null          | null             | null            |
| c3            | 2345678901       | xyz@gmail.com   |
| c8            | 3456789012       | pqr@hotmail.com |
| null          | null             | mnk@GMAIL.COM   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line just before the code which converts map to columns:

```py
df = df.withColumn('map_col', F.expr("transform_keys(map_col, (k, v) -> concat(k, '_2'))"))
```

This uses [`transform_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform_keys) which changes the key names adding `_2` to the originam name, as you needed.