# Accessing a Nested Map column in Spark Dataframes without using explode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a column in a Spark dataframe where the schema looks something like this:

```
|-- seg: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- expiry: long (nullable = false)
```

The value in the column looks something like this:

```
Map(10000124 -> WrappedArray([20185255,1561507200], [20185256,1561507200]))]
```

What I want to do it create a column from this Map column which only contain an array of [20185255,20185256] (The elements of the array are 1st element of each array in the WrappedArray). **How do I do this ?**

I am trying not to use "explode".

** Also is their a way I can use a UDF which take in the Map and get those values ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)