# How can I create a dataframe out of a nested JSON?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So my initial schema looks like this:

```
root  
|-- database: String  
|-- table: String  
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)  
|    |-- element1: Int  
|    |-- element2: Char
```

The `show()` result has one data column that's ugly with `[null,2,3]` etc

What I want to do is to make the data struct into it's own dataframe so I can have the nested json's data spread out among columns but something like:

`val dfNew = df.select("data")` only really gets me the same gross column when I use `show()` instead of the multiple columns specified by the schema `(element1, element2)` etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

Comment: Check out [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
case class Data(element1: Int, element2: String)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Array(
        (1, Data(12312, "test"))))).toDF("i", "data")

df.select(col("data.element1"), col("data.element2"))
```

or this?

```
df.select(col("data.*"))
```

Comment: Along that, I'd like to be able to do it without specifying each column so I could just take all that are available.

Comment: That second one looks like what I want. I tried this   
val dfdata2 = df.select(df.col("data.*"))  
And it didn't work, only one column.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work for me, but this does `val dfdata2 = df.selectExpr("data.*")` and apparently this one too: `val dfdata = df.select("data.*")`