# spark UDF operate on array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe like:

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|a            |destination                               |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|[a,Alice,1]  |[[b,Bob,0], [e,Esther,0], [h,Fraudster,1]]|
|[e,Esther,0] |[[f,Fanny,0], [d,David,0]]                |
|[c,Charlie,0]|[[b,Bob,0]]                               |
|[b,Bob,0]    |[[c,Charlie,0]]                           |
|[f,Fanny,0]  |[[c,Charlie,0], [h,Fraudster,1]]          |
|[d,David,0]  |[[a,Alice,1], [e,Esther,0]]               |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
```

with a schema of

```
|-- destination: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- var_only_0_and_1: integer (nullable = false)
```

how can I construct an UDF which operates on the column `destination`, i.e. the wrapped array created by `collect_list` UDF of spark to calculate the mean of the variable `var_only_0_and_1`?

Comment: Why the down vote? I know about explode, but would prefer a solution like http://faculty.ucmerced.edu/frusu/Papers/Conference/2017-hpdc-array-udf.pdf

Comment: And falling back to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931796/spark-udf-for-structtype-row will mess with Tungstens optimizations

Answer (score 5):

You can operate directly on the array as long you get the method signature of the UDF correct (something that has hit me hard in the past). Array columns become visible to a UDF as a Seq, and a Struct as a Row, so you'll need something like this:

```
def test (in:Seq[Row]): String = {
  // return a named field from the second struct in the array
  in(2).getAs[String]("var_only_0_and_1")
}

var udftest = udf(test _)
```

I've tested this on data looking like yours. I'm guessing its possible to iterate over the fields of the Seq[Row] in order to achieve what you want.

To be honest, I'm not at all sure about the type safety of doing this, and I believe that explode is the preferable way to do it as per @ayplam. Inbuilt functions will generally be fast than any UDF that a dev provides, as Spark cannot optimise a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native spark sql functions for this.

```
df.withColumn("dest",explode(col("destination")).
groupBy("a").agg(avg(col("dest").getField("var_only_0_and_1")))
```

Comment: But explode doesn't really look efficient. Is there a way to operate directly on the array?