# Why the input type Spark UDF is Row for struct column? How is it implemented in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

For single column, the input type of UDF is the dataType of this column, while for struct column, the input type is Row, why and how is it implemented?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val sub_schema = StructType(StructField("col1",ArrayType(IntegerType,false),true) :: StructField("col2",StringType,true)::Nil)
val schema = StructType(StructField("subtable", sub_schema,true) :: Nil)
val data = Seq(Row(Row(Array(1,2),"eb")),  Row(Row(Array(3,2,1), "dsf")) )
val rd = sc.parallelize(data)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rd, schema)
df.printSchema

val u =  udf((x:Row) => x, sub_schema)

root
 |-- subtable: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

[Spark UDF for StructType / Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931796/spark-udf-for-structtype-row?rq=1)

Comment: Could explain why do you find it unusual? What else would you expect?

Comment: Because the input type of UDF is by convention, which is implemented using reflection and can not be inferred by static type checking.