# Pyspark - How do you split a column with Struct Values of type Datetime?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code which creates windows and aggregates values in the windows.

```
df.groupBy(window("time", "30 minutes"))\
  .agg(func.countDistinct("customer_numbers")
```

The window column (column that holds the time periods) is now a struct with two datetimes.

```
[datetime1, datetime2].
```

My dataframe looks like this :

```
window                                       customer_numbers
[2018-02-04:10:00:00, 2018-02-04:10:30:00]          10
[2018-02-04:10:30:00, 2018-02-04:11:00:00]          15
```

I want it to look like this

```
start                             End               customer_numbers
2018-02-04:10:00:00        2018-02-04:10:30:00        10
2018-02-04:10:30:00        2018-02-04:11:00:00        15
```

I want to split this out into two columns and get rid of the original window column but i cant seem to find a way to do this. I tried using UDFs  though i think in scala you can simply do something like to get the first item i do not know how to do this in pyspark. I tried adding a UDF but instead of it giving me the first value it gave me a calendar.

```
.withColumn("key", $"window"._1)
```

Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `select` function as

```
.select(func.col('window')[0].alias('start'), func.col('window')[1].alias('end'), func.col('customer_numbers')).drop('window')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, though i had to explicitly name the struct types instead of using [0] and [1]