# Fetch values from nested struct in Spark DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark DF with one column, where each row is of the

Type:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

Form:

```
  col1: array (nullable = true)
|     |-- A1: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |       |-- B1: struct (nullable = true)
|     |       |    |-- B11: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |    |-- B12: string (nullable = true)

|     |       |-- B2: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to get the value of

```
A1->B1->B11.
```

Any methods to fetch this with the DataFrame APIs or indexing without converting each row into a seq and then iterating through it which affects my performance badly. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

Comment: Do you mean: `df.select(explode($"col1")).select($"A1.B1.B11")` ?

Comment: @TomLous Conceptually yes.

Comment: What about it doesn't -technically- work for you?

Comment: @TomLous You mean try this exact command you have given?