# How do I use a from_json() dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to create a dataset from a json-string within a dataframe in Databricks 3.5 (Spark 2.2.1). In the code block below 'jsonSchema' is a StructType with the correct layout for the json-string which is in the 'body' column of the dataframe.

```
val newDF = oldDF.select(from_json($"body".cast("string"), jsonSchema))
```

This returns a dataframe where the root object is

```
jsontostructs(CAST(body AS STRING)):struct
```

followed by the fields in the schema (looks correct). When I try another select on the newDF

```
val transform = newDF.select($"propertyNameInTheParsedJsonObject")
```

it throws the exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`columnName`' given 
input columns: [jsontostructs(CAST(body AS STRING))];;
```

I'm aparently missing something. I hoped from_json would return a dataframe I could manipulate further.

My ultimate objective is to cast the json-string within the oldDF body-column to a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from_json` returns a `struct` or (`array<struct<...>>`) column. It means it is a nested object. If you've provided a meaningful name:

```
val newDF = oldDF.select(from_json($"body".cast("string"), jsonSchema) as "parsed")
```

and the schema describes a plain `struct` you could use [standard methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494/10545309) like

```
newDF.select($"parsed.propertyNameInTheParsedJsonObject")
```

otherwise please follow the instructions for accessing arrays.

Comment: Thanks, indeed giving the returned struct a name was the key.