# How to change column of array to separate columns in spark scala?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a column with arrays in it:

```
"subscriberPhoneNbrs" : [
        {
            "phoneType" : "HOM",
            "phoneNbr" : "9045682704"
        },
        {
            "phoneType" : "WRK",
            "phoneNbr" : "9045749004"
        }
    ]
```

I want to separate the array and give as different columns as below:

```
"subWorkPhone" : "9045682704",
"subHomePhone" : "9045749004",
```

Tried using explode function but I am not getting expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a list of columns to select:

```
case class Phone(phoneType: String, phoneNbr: String)

val df = List((0, List(Phone("HOM", "1234"), Phone("WRK", "5678")))).toDF("id", "subscriberPhoneNbrs")
df.show(false)

val dfMap = df.select(map_from_entries($"subscriberPhoneNbrs") as "phoneMap")

val renameMap = Map("WRK" -> "subWorkPhone", "HOM" -> "subHomePhone")
val newCols = renameMap.map(kv => col(s"phoneMap.${kv._1}").alias(kv._2)).toList

dfMap.select(newCols: _*).show
```

Will result in the following:

```
+------------+------------+
|subWorkPhone|subHomePhone|
+------------+------------+
|        5678|        1234|
+------------+------------+
```

[map_from_entries doc :](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

```
static Column   map_from_entries(Column e)
Returns a map created from the given array of entries.
```

Comment: not found: value map_from_entries

error while executing the code in spark shell

Comment: Although my answer has been accepted, I'm interested if someone have a better solution.