# Spark JSON extract element from ArrayType()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple JSON files with a structure similar to these ones

```
{
"fields": [ 
 {
   "a": 1,
   "b": "Mike",
   "c": "Jordan"
 },
 {
  "a": 2,
  "b": "Filip",
  "c": "White"
 }
]
}
```

---

```
{
"fields":{
  "a": 2,
  "b": "Mark",
  "c": "Brown"
 }
}
```

which I load in the same DataFrame

```
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).json("/path/to/jsons")
```

I need to **extract only** the value for **"b"** when **"a" = 2** (in this case Mark and Filip).
I have 2 problems:

- "fields" contains 2 different types (Struct and Array(Struct)) in the same column
- how to extract only field "b"

I'm using PySpark. 
Thanks in advance.

```
df.withColumn("b values", col("fields") ... ??)
```

Comment: try `df.withColumn("b values", col("fields.b"))`

Comment: @RaphaelRoth this will return me an array of all b fields, also those where a != 2, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

Comment: there is no way to handle both schemas with one dataset/dataframe. You need to separate the two file types somehow or just transform everything into the array type

Answer (score 2):

Handle them separately and then union the results:

```py
df = spark.read.options(multiLine=True).json('/FileStore/tables/fields.json')
df1 = spark.read.options(multiLine=True).json('/FileStore/tables/fields2.json')
df = df.select(explode(df['fields']))
df = df.select('col.a','col.b','col.c')
df1 = df1.select('fields.a','fields.b','fields.c')
DF = df.union(df1)
DF = DF.where(DF['a'] == 2).select(DF['b']).show()

+-----+
|    b|
+-----+
|Filip|
| Mark|
+-----+
```